# How to convert text to binary code in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, binary

**I want JavaScript to translate text in a textarea into binary code.**

For example, if a user types in "`TEST`" into the textarea, the value "`01010100 01000101 01010011 01010100`" should be returned.

I would like to avoid using a switch statement to assign each character a binary code value (e.g. `case "T": return "01010100`) or any other similar technique.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fA24Y/) to show what I mean. Is this possible in native JavaScript?

Comment: Found this through Google. I think it's what you're looking for. http://www.roubaixinteractive.com/PlayGround/Binary_Conversion/Binary_To_Text.asp

Comment: you have charCodeAt method for strings in js

Comment: People should be aware that strings are stored as UTF-16 in JavaScript. Therefore, you'll have UTF-16 binary representation. If you want something else, UTF-8 for instance, you have to manually convert charcodes to UTF-8 before encoding to binary (exemple [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729405/how-to-convert-utf8-string-to-byte-array)).

Answer (score 77, accepted):

What you should do is convert every char using `charCodeAt` function to get the Ascii Code in decimal. Then you can convert it to Binary value using `toString(2)`:

```js
function convert() {
  var output = document.getElementById("ti2");
  var input = document.getElementById("ti1").value;
  output.value = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      output.value += input[i].charCodeAt(0).toString(2) + " ";
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="ti1" value ="TEST"/>
<input id="ti2"/>
<button onClick="convert();">Convert!</button>
```

And here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fA24Y/1/

Comment: Alternate way to left pad : `var a = 'a'.charCodeAt(0).toString(2); /* a == "1100001" */ a = new Array(9 - a.length).join('0') + a; /* a == "01100001" */`.

Comment: Question: Isn't there another way to do it, like make a blob with this text and then using filereader output it as binary data....however it just seems to output the text for me.

Comment: This actually produced characters when I input certain strings in a loop, so there is something wrong with this function. alejandro's answer however works.

Comment: Note for future readers: Be aware that the charset is not limited to 8 bits. Try `charToBin("")`

Comment: Why not "input.charCodeAt(i)" instead?

Comment: This has an issue with leading zeros. 
`output.value += (0b100000000 + input[i].charCodeAt(0)).toString(2).substring(1) + " ";` fixes it

Comment: or just `'1100'.padStart(8, '0')` => '00001100`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Answer (score 50):

This might be the simplest you can get:

```
function text2Binary(string) {
    return string.split('').map(function (char) {
        return char.charCodeAt(0).toString(2);
    }).join(' ');
}
```

Comment: +1 for the "join", fixing trailing space of the accepted answer. You may also add `.padStart(8,'0')` to force each caracter to be on 8 bits.

Answer (score 12):

1. traverse the string
2. convert every character to their char code
3. convert the char code to binary
4. push it into an array and add the left 0s
5. return a string separated by space

Code:

```
function textToBin(text) {
  var length = text.length,
      output = [];
  for (var i = 0;i < length; i++) {
    var bin = text[i].charCodeAt().toString(2);
    output.push(Array(8-bin.length+1).join("0") + bin);
  } 
  return output.join(" ");
}
textToBin("!a") => "00100001 01100001"
```

Another way

```
function textToBin(text) {
  return (
    Array
      .from(text)
      .reduce((acc, char) => acc.concat(char.charCodeAt().toString(2)), [])
      .map(bin => '0'.repeat(8 - bin.length) + bin )
      .join(' ')
  );
}
```

Comment: You can omit the `+1` in in `9-bin.length+1` by making the `8` a `9` like this ```function textToBin(text) {
  var length = text.length,
      output = [];
  for (var i = 0;i < length; i++) {
    var bin = text[i].charCodeAt().toString(2);
    output.push(Array(9-bin.length).join("0") + bin);
  } 
  return output.join(" ");
}```

Comment: Simpler is `output.push(('0000000' + bin).slice(-8))`. ;-) But some characters, like endash, are more than 8 bits: charCode 8212 -> 10000000010100.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a pretty generic, native implementation, that [I wrote some time ago](https://gist.github.com/eyecatchup/6742657),

```
// ABC - a generic, native JS (A)scii(B)inary(C)onverter.
// (c) 2013 Stephan Schmitz <eyecatchup@gmail.com>
// License: MIT, http://eyecatchup.mit-license.org
// URL: https://gist.github.com/eyecatchup/6742657
var ABC = {
  toAscii: function(bin) {
    return bin.replace(/\s*[01]{8}\s*/g, function(bin) {
      return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(bin, 2))
    })
  },
  toBinary: function(str, spaceSeparatedOctets) {
    return str.replace(/[\s\S]/g, function(str) {
      str = ABC.zeroPad(str.charCodeAt().toString(2));
      return !1 == spaceSeparatedOctets ? str : str + " "
    })
  },
  zeroPad: function(num) {
    return "00000000".slice(String(num).length) + num
  }
};
```

and to be used as follows:

```
var binary1      = "01100110011001010110010101101100011010010110111001100111001000000110110001110101011000110110101101111001",
    binary2      = "01100110 01100101 01100101 01101100 01101001 01101110 01100111 00100000 01101100 01110101 01100011 01101011 01111001",
    binary1Ascii = ABC.toAscii(binary1),
    binary2Ascii = ABC.toAscii(binary2);

console.log("Binary 1:                   " + binary1);
console.log("Binary 1 to ASCII:          " + binary1Ascii);
console.log("Binary 2:                   " + binary2);
console.log("Binary 2 to ASCII:          " + binary2Ascii);
console.log("Ascii to Binary:            " + ABC.toBinary(binary1Ascii));     // default: space-separated octets
console.log("Ascii to Binary /wo spaces: " + ABC.toBinary(binary1Ascii, 0));  // 2nd parameter false to not space-separate octets
```

Source is on Github (gist): https://gist.github.com/eyecatchup/6742657

Hope it helps. Feel free to use for whatever you want *(well, at least for whatever MIT permits)*.

Answer (score 7):

```
var PADDING = "00000000"

var string = "TEST"
var resultArray = []

for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
  var compact = string.charCodeAt(i).toString(2)
  var padded  = compact.substring(0, PADDING.length - compact.length) + compact

  resultArray.push(padded)
}

console.log(resultArray.join(" "))
```

Comment: There is a problem with your code, I've checked the results here- http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/ascii-text-to-binary-converter  here - http://www.roubaixinteractive.com/PlayGround/Binary_Conversion/Binary_To_Text.asp and here - http://string-functions.com/string-binary.aspx

Your code always put "1" at the first number.

Comment: @Kasmetski That's true, you need the next code to make it work: `var padded  = PADDING.substring(0, PADDING.length - compact.length) + compact`

Answer (score 6):

The other answers will work for most cases. But it's worth noting that `charCodeAt()` and related don't work with UTF-8 strings (that is, they throw errors if there are any characters outside the standard ASCII range). Here's a workaround.

```
// UTF-8 to binary
var utf8ToBin = function( s ){
    s = unescape( encodeURIComponent( s ) );
    var chr, i = 0, l = s.length, out = '';
    for( ; i < l; i ++ ){
        chr = s.charCodeAt( i ).toString( 2 );
        while( chr.length % 8 != 0 ){ chr = '0' + chr; }
        out += chr;
    }
    return out;
};

// Binary to UTF-8
var binToUtf8 = function( s ){
    var i = 0, l = s.length, chr, out = '';
    for( ; i < l; i += 8 ){
        chr = parseInt( s.substr( i, 8 ), 2 ).toString( 16 );
        out += '%' + ( ( chr.length % 2 == 0 ) ? chr : '0' + chr );
    }
    return decodeURIComponent( out );
};
```

The `escape/unescape()` functions are deprecated. If you need polyfills for them, you can check out the more comprehensive UTF-8 encoding example found here: http://jsfiddle.net/47zwb41o

Answer (score 5):

Just a hint into the right direction

```
var foo = "TEST",
    res = [ ];

foo.split('').forEach(function( letter ) {
    var bin     = letter.charCodeAt( 0 ).toString( 2 ),
        padding = 8 - bin.length;

    res.push( new Array( padding+1 ).join( '0' ) + bin );
});

console.log( res );
```

Answer (score 5):

8-bit characters with leading 0

```
'sometext'
        .split('')
        .map((char) => '00'.concat(char.charCodeAt(0).toString(2)).slice(-8))
        .join(' ');
```

If you need 6 or 7 bit, just change `.slice(-8)`

Answer (score 5):

Thank you **Majid Laissi** for your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14430733/3936149)

I made 2 functions out from your code:

the goal was to implement convertation of string to VARBINARY, BINARY and back

```
const stringToBinary = function(string, maxBytes) {
  //for BINARY maxBytes = 255
  //for VARBINARY maxBytes = 65535
  let binaryOutput = '';
  if (string.length > maxBytes) {
    string = string.substring(0, maxBytes);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    binaryOutput += string[i].charCodeAt(0).toString(2) + ' ';
  }

  return binaryOutput;
};
```

and backward convertation:

```
const binaryToString = function(binary) {
  const arrayOfBytes = binary.split(' ');

  let stringOutput = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfBytes.length; i++) {
    stringOutput += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(arrayOfBytes[i], 2));
  }

  return stringOutput;
};
```

and here is a working example: https://jsbin.com/futalidenu/edit?js,console

Answer (score 4):

Provided you're working in node or a browser with `BigInt` support, this version cuts costs by saving the expensive string construction for the very end:

```js
const zero = 0n
const shift = 8n

function asciiToBinary (str) {
  const len = str.length
  let n = zero
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    n = (n << shift) + BigInt(str.charCodeAt(i))
  }
  return n.toString(2).padStart(len * 8, 0)
}
```

It's about twice as fast as the other solutions mentioned here including this simple es6+ implementation:

```js
const toBinary = s => [...s]
  .map(x => x
    .codePointAt()
    .toString(2)
    .padStart(8,0)
  )
  .join('')
```

If you need to handle unicode characters, here's this guy:

```js
const zero = 0n
const shift = 8n
const bigShift = 16n
const byte = 255n

function unicodeToBinary (str) {
  const len = str.length
  let n = zero
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    const bits = BigInt(str.codePointAt(i))
    n = (n << (bits > byte ? bigShift : shift)) + bits
  }
  const bin = n.toString(2)
  return bin.padStart(8 * Math.ceil(bin.length / 8), 0)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

this seems to be the simplified version

```
Array.from('abc').map((each)=>each.charCodeAt(0).toString(2)).join(" ")
```

Answer (score 3):

This is as short as you can get. It's based on the top-rated answer but transformed to a reduce function.

```
"TEST".split("").reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b.charCodeAt(0).toString(2)}, "")
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const textToBinary = (string) => {
    return string.split('').map((char) => 
      char.charCodeAt().toString(2)).join(' ');
}

console.log(textToBinary('hello world'))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
var UTF8ToBin=function(f){for(var a,c=0,d=(f=unescape(encodeURIComponent(f))).length,b="";c<d;c++){for(a=f.charCodeAt(c).toString(2);a.length%8!=0;){a="0"+a}b+=a}return b},binToUTF8=function(f){for(var a,c=0,d=f.length,b="";c<d;c+=8){b+="%"+((a=parseInt(f.substr(c,8),2).toString(16)).length%2==0?a:"0"+a)}return decodeURIComponent(b)};
```

This is a small minified JavaScript Code to convert UTF8 to Binary and Vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution for **UTF-8**-based textual binary representation. It leverages [`TextEncoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder), which encodes a string to its UTF-8 bytes.

This solution separates characters by spaces. The individual "byte-bits" of multi-byte characters are separated by a minus character (`-`).

```js
// inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/40031979/923560
function stringToUtf8BinaryRepresentation(inputString) {
  const result = Array.from(inputString).map(
    char => [... new TextEncoder().encode(char)].map(
      x => x.toString(2).padStart(8, '0')
    ).join('-')
  ).join(' ');
  return result;
}

// ### example usage #########################
function print(inputString) {
  console.log("--------------");
  console.log(inputString);
  console.log(stringToUtf8BinaryRepresentation(inputString));
}

// compare with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding
// compare with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout
// compare with UTF-16, which JavaScript uses for strings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Examples

print("TEST");
print("hello world");
print("$");
print("£");
print("€");
print("한");
print("");
print("παράδειγμα");

print("");
print("‍‍‍");
print("‍‍");
print("");
```

Answer (score 0):

use the code: `'text'.split('').map(e=>{return e.charCodeAt(0).toString(2)})` e.g.-

```
const text='some text';
const output=text.split('').map(e=>{return e.charCodeAt(0).toString(2)})
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple using Buffer

```js
const text = "TEST";
[...Buffer.from(text).values()]                   // [ 84, 69, 83, 84 ]
    .map(byte => byte.toString(2).padStart(8, 0)) // [ '01010100', '01000101', '01010011', '01010100' ]                        
    .join(' ')                                    // '01010100 01000101 01010011 01010100'
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest and simplest solution:

```
"x".charCodeAt().toString(2) // 1111000
```

[String.charCodeAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) `charCodeAt(0)` returns unicode: `"x".charCodeAt() // 120`

[Object.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) `charCodeAt().toString(2)` converts unicode to binary.

---

For multiple string characters:

```
[..."Tesla"].map((i) => i.charCodeAt().toString(2)).join(" ");
// 1010100 1100101 1110011 1101100 1100001
```

[Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
`[..."Tesla"] // ['T', 'e', 's', 'l', 'a']`

[Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
`[..."Tesla"].map((i) => i.charCodeAt()) // [84, 101, 115, 108, 97]`

[Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) Put a space `" "` after each element in the array `map(i)` and convert the array to string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can do something like this:
Returns a STRING:

```js
    const toBinary = (str)=>{
        let r = []
        for (let i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
            r.push(str.charCodeAt(i).toString(2));
        }
        return r.join("");
    }
```

Or, as an int:

```js
    const toBinary = (str)=>{
        let r = []
        for (let i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
            r.push(str.charCodeAt(i).toString(2));
        }
        return parseInt(r.join(""));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert text to binary in Javascript we must first transform the text to its decimal character code then take the binary value of that code, we must also take into account padding leading zeros and characters that can be greater then one byte.

```js
const textarea = document.body.querySelector('textarea');

document.body.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input',function(){

    textarea.value = this.value
    .split('')
    .map((char)=>{
      const bin = char.charCodeAt(0).toString(2);
      return (
       (
        Array(
          (
            Math.ceil(bin.length/8)*8
          )
          -bin.length+1
        )
        .join("0")
       )
       +bin
     );
   })
   .join('');

});
```

```html
<input placeholder="Enter String">
<textarea id="conversion" placeholder="Conversion" readonly></textarea>
```