# Converting a hexadecimal string to base64 in javascript

Tags: javascript, base64, md5

Now I have a string of a MD5 hex digest for a file, and I want to convert it to base64 in order to use the Content-MD5 HTTP header when uploading it.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5):

```
var hexArray = myHexString
    .replace(/\r|\n/g, "")
    .replace(/([\da-fA-F]{2}) ?/g, "0x$1 ")
    .replace(/ +$/, "")
    .split(" ");
var byteString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, hexArray);
var base64string = window.btoa(byteString);
```

See here for btoa docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa

Also for polyfill: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23190164/275501

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers has built in functions for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

For older browsers you'll need a library such as https://github.com/beatgammit/base64-js

Comment: How to convert a hexadecimal string to a  string that can be used in these methods?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23190056/hex-to-base64-converter-for-javascript

Comment: He didn't ask about encoding the hex representation into Base64 but how to encode the underlying data represented by the hex string. There is no point in encoding hex string representation into Base64.