# using cryptojs to generate RFC 2104-compliant HMAC with SHA256 algorithm

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, cryptojs

im am following [this amazon documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/rest-signature.html) in an attempt to find the algorithm to generate a signature in javascript. I cannot seem to get it to work.

```
// html
// <head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/sha256.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/hmac.min.js"></script>
// body (javascript)
var test_string = "GET\nwebservices.amazon.com\n/onca/xml\nAWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE&AssociateTag=mytag-20&ItemId=0679722769&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Images%2CItemAttributes%2COffers%2CReviews&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2014-08-18T12%3A00%3A00Z&Version=2013-08-01"

var signature2 = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(test_string, "1234567890");
console.log(signature2.toString());
```

I amd getting `8fb6d93342d767d797799aee4ea5a6d8322f0d8554537c313cfa69fa25f1cd07`

I should be getting `j7bZM0LXZ9eXeZruTqWm2DIvDYVUU3wxPPpp+iXxzQc=`

Hmmm anyone knows whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong, it's just that the string you got represents an array of bytes (with their hex representation). So all you need to do is Base 64 encode this array of bytes and you will get the exact same result. Checkout it out here, paste your hex represented byte array and base 64 encode it: http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en

As far as how this can be done, well, you may have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23190056/hex-to-base64-converter-for-javascript) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30613897/converting-a-hexadecimal-string-to-base64-in-javascript).

---

UPDATE:

As pointed out in the comments it seems that there's a built-in way in cryptojs to convert directly to base64:

```
console.log(signature2.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
```

Comment: `console.log(signature2.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));`

Comment: Oh, good to know that there's a built-in way to achieve this. Thanks for pointing this out. I will update my answer to include this information.

Comment: It's fine. Note that the enc-base64.min.js might need to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(message, secret_key);
 let result = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
```

I'm posting this solution here since I'm trying to do this exact same exercise in ReactNative, and ReactNative doesn't like npm's base crypto package. CryptoJS works as a replacement.

NOTE: (this was infuriating) I had to get rid of the first \n, though Amazon specifically tells you to prepend the lines with breaks and the GET has a line space above it in their example..

*FULL SOLUTION:*

```
 let secret_key = "1234567890";
 let message = 'GET' +
 '\nwebservices.amazon.com' +
 '\n/onca/xml' +
 '\nAWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE&AssociateTag=mytag-20&ItemId=0679722769&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Images%2CItemAttributes%2COffers%2CReviews&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2014-08-18T12%3A00%3A00Z&Version=2013-08-01'

 let hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(message, secret_key);
 let result = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
 console.log('MARK: RESULT ', result);
```