# Hash code which contains more than 16 characters?

Tags: javascript, ruby, hash, md5, radix

I would like to apply a hash code solution on my webpage which is more compact than MD5 and SHA-1, because I want to use them as keys in a JSON hash table.

Or equivalently: how can I convert a hexadecimal MD5 hash to a higher base number system? The higher the better, till the words can be used as keys in a JSON hash. For example instead of:

```
"684591beaa2c8e2438be48524f555141" hexadecimal MD5 hash I would prefer "668e15r60463kya64xq7umloh" which is a base 36 number and the values are equal.
```

I made the calculation in Ruby:

```
"684591beaa2c8e2438be48524f555141".to_i(16).to_s(36)
=> 668e15r60463kya64xq7umloh
```

Because it handles the big decimal value of the hexadecimal MD5 hash (138600936100279876740703998180777611585)

Unlike JavaScript, in JavaScript I get a float value, which is rounded. So I get the same 36-base value for different MD5 hashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Ruby

You could return [`base64digest`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest/Instance.html#method-i-base64digest) directly :

```
require 'digest'

Digest::MD5.hexdigest 'your_page'
#=> "a6b580481008e60df9350de170b7e728"

p Digest::MD5.base64digest 'your_page'
#=> "prWASBAI5g35NQ3hcLfnKA=="
```

## Javascript

If you already have a hex string, a comment from this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23190056/6419007) seems to work fine :

```
btoa("a6b580481008e60df9350de170b7e728".match(/\w{2}/g).map(function(a){return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(a, 16));} ).join(""))
#=> "prWASBAI5g35NQ3hcLfnKA=="
```

Comment: I see, but I want to achieve the calculation on a webpage with JavaScript.

Comment: I wasn't sure, since you tagged `Ruby` and showed Ruby code.

Comment: Thx, that is what I want, I already have a md5.js library to calculate the md5 hashes.