# HexString to Base64 in angular typescript

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, base64

I used to change hexString like 0B81040000001E to C4EEAAAAHg==

I used web site http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php

but problem is that I want to implement this change process in my angular app

many people says I should use btoa(0B81040000001E) to change hexstring to base64. 
but when I tried, result came to different like "MEI4MTA0MDAwMDAwMUU=" 
Not "C4EEAAAAHg=="

did I use something wrong? 
value "C4EEAAAAHg==" is the one that I think I should get.

C4EEAAAAHg== is not base 64 that I know?

How can I change hexstring data to base 64...?

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/D%C3%A9coder_encoder_en_base64) explains that in details. Have you taken a look at it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HEX to Base64 converter for JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23190056/hex-to-base64-converter-for-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is how you can transform a HexString to Base64 :

```
let base64String = btoa("0B81040000001E".match(/\w{2}/g).map(a => {return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(a, 16));} ).join(""))
```

regards,