# Base64 representing PDF to blob - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf, blob

I have a Base64 string representing a PDF file.
I want to convert it to a file with the Blob object using javascript.
After it's done i want to save the blob as a PDF file using FileSaver.js.

Here is my code:

```
var base64PDF = JVBERi0xLjQNCiW0t..; // This is a huge string.
var blob = new Blob([base64PDF], { type: 'application/pdf' });
saveAs(blob, "test.pdf");
```

This code doesn't work. It saves a test.pdf that says it can't open this pdf because there was en error in the decoding.

I've also tried to do this:

```
var base64PDF = JVBERi0xLjQNCiW0t..; // This is a huge string.
var decode = atob(screen.prp_wcfria_ExternalFile.pdfFile);
var blob = new Blob([decode], { type: 'application/pdf' });
saveAs(blob, "test.pdf");
```

This code also doesn't work. How do i do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a Blob from a base64 string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 61):

This javascript converts a base64 string to a blob object:

```
// base64 string
var base64str = result.pdf;

// decode base64 string, remove space for IE compatibility
var binary = atob(base64str.replace(/\s/g, ''));
var len = binary.length;
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(len);
var view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    view[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
}

// create the blob object with content-type "application/pdf"               
var blob = new Blob( [view], { type: "application/pdf" });
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Comment: Great answer, but you should include an explanation of why like @Musa below.  Together you guys have the perfect answer.

Comment: Pretty easy. Thanks!!

Answer (score 9):

You have to convert the base64 string back into the original binary data. Using atob is not sufficient, you'll have to run it through a loop and convert it to an array buffer - [Convert base64 string to ArrayBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797299/convert-base64-string-to-arraybuffer)
Then use that to create the blob.

Comment: Great explanation thanks!  Could use an example like @Carlos includes, but together you have the perfect answer.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const b64toUrl = async (base64Data) => {
  const r = await fetch(base64Data);
  const blob = await r.blob();
  return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}
```

`base64Data` string should include the "`data:application/pdf;base64,....`" part.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Could you update this to include a non-async version? Putting code in comments sucks but basically, for those of you who can't use an await for this, you will need to use the more formal promise route (`fetch().then().then()`) to get your url.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way, use the Fetch API to convert base64 to blob.

here's the code...

```
    const pdfstr = await fetch(pdf);   \\pdf is the base64 string
    const blobFromFetch= await pdfstr.blob();

  
    var blob = new Blob([blobFromFetch], {type: "application/pdf"});
    
    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  

  window.open(blobUrl,"_blank");
```

hope it helps!

Comment: Your solution with making sure the pdf base64 string has the `data:application/pdf;base64,`string prepended, as suggested by Gerson Diniz answer, worked fine for me:
```await fetch(`data:application/pdf;base64,${pdf}`);```