# Render PDF in Edge and IE11 in an Embed

Tags: angular, pdf, angular5, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I thought I had a solution for this using an embed so that Adobe would render the PDF in the browsers when I did:

```
<embed src="./assets/pdf/example-1.pdf"
       width="100%"
       height="675px"
       style="border: 1px solid red"
       type="application/pdf">
```

But when I try to dynamically set the embed `src` using `URL.createObjectURL(blob)` and bind it to the `embed` in Angular it doesn't render:

```
<embed [src]="url"
       width="100%"
       height="675px"
       style="border: 1px solid red"
       type="application/pdf">
```

Is there more to rendering a PDF in an embed using a `blob` other then:

```
this.http(..., { responseType: 'blob', observe: 'response' })
  .subscribe((blob) => {

    url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    this.url = this.domSanitizer
      .bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  });
```

I know I can use PDF.js with Angular using a plugin, but I can't figure out how to use ViewerJS with it to get the controls for panning, zoom, etc.  So I just want to display the PDF sent down in the response using Adobe in Edge and IE11.  It can be in an `iframe`, but this only worked in Edge and not in IE11 with no displayed errors

For example, using this was suggested for cross browser compatibility when receiving a `base64` of the PDF, but it only works for Edge not IE11.

```
  // Default to Chrome
  let url = `data:application/pdf;base64,${src}`;

  // Internet Explorer 11 and Edge workaround
  if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    const byteCharacters = atob(src);
    const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
      byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    const blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });

    url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    if (this.url) {
      // Release URLs for performance and memory usage
      this.window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.url);
    }
  }

  this.url = this.domSanitizer
    .bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);


<iframe id="result"
        [src]="url"
        style="width: 100%; height: 95vh; border: 1px solid red;"
        sandbox></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This all works for IE11 if you **remove** the `sandbox` attribute from the iframe.  Sooo by removing security restrictions provided by `sandbox` IE11 works even though [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-sandbox) indicates it is compliant with IE11.

Comment: In case you're having an issue with converting Base64 to a Blob properly in order to render the PDF check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45872086/1148107