# How to create a blob or an arrayBuffer - Ionic 2 / Cordova

Tags: cordova, angular, typescript, ionic2, cordova-plugins

How to create a blob or an arrayBuffer with typescript using this method Camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData).

I'm using Ionic 2/Cordova.

```
var options = {
    quality: 90,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE
};

Camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {

    File.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(imageData).then((fileEntry: FileEntry) => {

    })

});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try this answer [Convert base64 string to ArrayBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797299/convert-base64-string-to-arraybuffer). execute _base64ToArrayBuffer on imageData. remember to remove destinationType as it defaults to dataUrl