# Convert base64 string into byte array through javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to convert "base64" string into bytes array through the javascript.

I received string from the URL like.

```
 ("data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QN6RXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAIA)
```

And i want to convert the string into bytes array. because i need this byte array to send Rest API endpoint. The rest API Content-type=application/octet-stream.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a Blob from a base64 string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert base64 string to ArrayBuffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797299/convert-base64-string-to-arraybuffer)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `XMLHttpRequest` to do the dirty work for you:

```js
var url = document.createElement("canvas").toDataURL(); // some data-uri

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhr.onload = function() {
  // result = ArrayBuffer, from here assign a view to it
  if (xhr.status === 200) console.log(new Uint8Array(xhr.response));
};
xhr.send();
```

It's a little more code than using `atob()` but all conversion happens internally. It's async too which can help with larger Data-URIs.

In newer browsers (which supports it) you can instead use `fetch()`:

```js
// note: atm not all browsers support these features.
fetch(document.createElement("canvas").toDataURL())  // pass in some data-uri
  .then(function(response) {return response.arrayBuffer()})
  .then(function(buffer) {
    console.log(new Uint8Array(buffer));
  });
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try with the following;

```
function test(base64StringFromURL)
{
   var parts = base64StringFromURL.split(";base64,");
   var contentType = parts[0].replace("data:", "");
   var base64 = parts[1];
   var byteArray = base64ToByteArray(base64);
   ..
}

function base64ToByteArray(base64String) {
        try {            
            var sliceSize = 1024;
            var byteCharacters = atob(base64String);
            var bytesLength = byteCharacters.length;
            var slicesCount = Math.ceil(bytesLength / sliceSize);
            var byteArrays = new Array(slicesCount);

            for (var sliceIndex = 0; sliceIndex < slicesCount; ++sliceIndex) {
                var begin = sliceIndex * sliceSize;
                var end = Math.min(begin + sliceSize, bytesLength);

                var bytes = new Array(end - begin);
                for (var offset = begin, i = 0; offset < end; ++i, ++offset) {
                    bytes[i] = byteCharacters[offset].charCodeAt(0);
                }
                byteArrays[sliceIndex] = new Uint8Array(bytes);
            }
            return byteArrays;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("Couldn't convert to byte array: " + e);
            return undefined;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This would prove to be much short solution.

```
const byteArray = new Buffer(base64String.replace(/^[\w\d;:\/]+base64\,/g, ''), 'base64');
```

> base64String is the string containing the base 64 string.

> byteArray is the array you need.

> The regex replacement is optional and is just there to deal with prefix as in the case of dataurl string.

Comment: Buffer is NodeJS not Javascript