# Import a private RSACryptoServiceProvider blob into CNGKey.Import

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa, cng

From a legacy program:

> bye[] rsaPrivateKeyExport = RSACryptoProvider.ExportCspBlob(true);

These keys are stored in a file.

As part of a legacy refresh, I need to use CNG RSA keys.

So something like reading the old blob and then converting:

> CngKey cngPrv = CngKey.Import(rsaPrvKeyExport,
>   CngKeyBlobFormat.GenericPrivateBlob);

But I cannot get this to work?

How do I convert the old blob type to the new one? Do I only use parts of the old blob?

The key length is 2048.

Answer (score 1):

`GenericPrivateBlob` is a CNG-specific format, it doesn't mean "try any private thing".

CNG is capable of opening CAPI key blobs, using the formats identified at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptexportkey.

```
private static readonly CngKeyBlobFormat s_legacyRsaPrivateBlobFormat =
    new CngKeyBlobFormat("CAPIPRIVATEBLOB");

...

byte[] exported;

using (RSACryptoServiceProvider a = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048))
{
    exported = a.ExportCspBlob(true);
}

RSA b;

using (CngKey key = CngKey.Import(exported, s_legacyRsaPrivateBlob))
{
    b = new RSACng(key);
}

// This using is broken out here just to show that the constructed object can safely outlive
// the CngKey object that it was created from.
using (b)
{
    ...
}
```