# Error RSA encrypting in C# and decrypting in Go

Tags: c#, go, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle

I am getting an error decrypting a message in go that was encrypted in C# (using corresponding public/private keys)

My client is written in C# and my server is written in Go. I generated a private and public key via go's crypto/rsa package (using `rsa.GenerateKey(random Reader, bits int)`). I then store the public key file generated where the client can access it and the private key where the server can access it. I encrypt on the client with the following code (using bouncy castle):

```
   public static string Encrypt(string plainText)
   {
      byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

      PemReader pr = new PemReader(
        new StringReader(m_publicKey)
      );
      RsaKeyParameters keys = (RsaKeyParameters)pr.ReadObject();

      // PKCS1 OAEP paddings
      OaepEncoding eng = new OaepEncoding(new RsaEngine());
      eng.Init(true, keys);

      int length = plainTextBytes.Length;
      int blockSize = eng.GetInputBlockSize();
      List<byte> cipherTextBytes = new List<byte>();
      for (int chunkPosition = 0; chunkPosition < length; chunkPosition += blockSize)
      {
          int chunkSize = Math.Min(blockSize, length - chunkPosition);
          cipherTextBytes.AddRange(eng.ProcessBlock(
              plainTextBytes, chunkPosition, chunkSize
          ));
      }
      return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes.ToArray());
}
```

The go server parses this string from the header and uses the private key to decrypt:

```
func DecryptWithPrivateKey(ciphertext []byte, priv *rsa.PrivateKey) []byte {
   hash := sha512.New()

   plaintext, err := rsa.DecryptOAEP(hash, rand.Reader, priv, ciphertext, nil)
   if err != nil {
       fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, err.Error())
   }
   return plaintext
}
```

The decryption function throws `crypto/rsa: decryption error`. If I try pasting the cipher text directly into go (rather then sending from the client), the same error occurs.

NOTE: in order to get the public key to load, I needed to change the header from:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY----- 
...
```

to

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- 
...
```

and the same for the footer. I am assuming this is a formatting issue but not sure how to go about solving.

EDIT: it seems that golang OAEP uses sha256 and bouncy castle uses SHA-1. Go's documentation specifies that the hash for encryption and decryption must be the same. This seems likely to be the issue? If it is, how can I change the hashing algorithm used by either go or C#?

Comment: I tried using the altered header for the public key in go, and it worked (was able to encrypt and decrypt), so that isn't it.

Comment: I also tried pasting the raw byte values into go and it still didn't work. So that isn't it either.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46937690/1820553

Comment: Also,  you forgot to decode the base64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to match the hash. In GoLang you've already set it to SHA-512 if I take a look at your code. Using SHA-256 at minimum should probably be preferred, but using SHA-1 is relatively safe as the MGF1 function doesn't rely on the collision resistance of the underlying hash. It's also the default for most runtimes, I don't know why GoLang decided against that.

Probably the best is to set SHA-512 for both runtimes, so [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsaencryptionpadding.oaepsha512?view=net-5.0) is the necessary constant for .NET.

---

Note that the underlying story is even more complex as OAEP uses a hash over a label as well as a hash within MGF1 (mask generation function 1, the only one specified). Both need to be specified in advance and generally the same hash function is used, but [sometimes it is not](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19974).

The label is generally empty and most runtimes don't even allow setting it, so the hash value over the label is basically a hash-function specific constant that doesn't matter for security. The constant just manages to make things incompatible; "More flexible" isn't always a good thing.