# Unsupported array-like object error when decryption using aes-js library in CBC mode

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using [aes-js](https://github.com/ricmoo/aes-js) library to test AES encryption . When I try to decrypt a ciphertext, I am getting the following error

> Error: unsupported array-like object
>           at coerceArray (/data/data/com.suspendresume/files/nodejs-project/node_modules/aes-js/index.js:51:15)
>           at new ModeOfOperationCBC (/data/data/com.suspendresume/files/nodejs-project/node_modules/aes-js/index.js:442:33)
>           at MyEmitter.rn_bridge.channel.on (/data/data/com.suspendresume/files/nodejs-project/main.js:76:15)
>           at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
>           at MyEmitter.emit (events.js:210:7)
>           at Immediate.setImmediate [as _onImmediate] (/data/data/com.suspendresume/files/nodejs-builtin_modules/rn-bridge/index.js:14:13)
>           at runCallback (timers.js:781:20)
>           at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:743:5)
>           at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:714:5)

The following is my code

```
 encryptedHex ='yRe2x6Gf2uVzfesp1I7ISkkAjTo2xoH2SPSqXzdWKHg+HhosYblfTFUJVoPVgpyf'
  iv= 'ec8902010adc3d63';
  key='aa54c24fae5e52a5861c80f466a90922'
  key= aesjs.utils.hex.toBytes(key)
 // When ready to decrypt the hex string, convert it back to bytes
 var encryptedBytes = aesjs.utils.hex.toBytes(encryptedHex);

 // The cipher-block chaining mode of operation maintains internal
 // state, so to decrypt a new instance must be instantiated.

 var aesCbc = new aesjs.ModeOfOperation.cbc(key, iv);
 var decryptedBytes = aesCbc.decrypt(encryptedBytes);

 // Convert our bytes back into text
 var decryptedText = aesjs.utils.utf8.fromBytes(decryptedBytes);
 console.log(decryptedText);
```

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. The Initialization Vector must also be passed as an array.
2. The Initialization Vector [must be of length 16 bytes](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/50786) (that is 32 in hex). Yours is only 8 bytes.
3. The variable called `encryptedHex` doesn't contain hex but it contains base64. Hex only allows numbers and the letters A-F, but the string contains other letters and even `+`.

I have solved these issues like this:

1. Convert it to bytes using `aesjs.utils.hex.toBytes`
2. Since I don't have the original 16 bytes IV, I can't decrypt your text. Instead, I have created a new encrypted text, IV and Key to demonstrate that the code works.
3. I convert the base64 string into an Uint8Array using [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41106346/1492977).

Here's the result. It should print `Hello` in the console:

```js
encryptedB64 = 'kcGz8P/m0lRRRxcT3tJiSw==';

iv = '6162636465666768696a6b6c6d6e6f70';
iv = aesjs.utils.hex.toBytes(iv);

key = '31323334353637383930313233343536';
key = aesjs.utils.hex.toBytes(key);

// When ready to decrypt the base64 string, convert it back to bytes
var encryptedBytes = Uint8Array.from(atob(encryptedB64), c => c.charCodeAt(0));

// The cipher-block chaining mode of operation maintains internal
// state, so to decrypt a new instance must be instantiated.

var aesCbc = new aesjs.ModeOfOperation.cbc(key, iv);
var decryptedBytes = aesCbc.decrypt(encryptedBytes);

// Convert our bytes back into text
var decryptedText = aesjs.utils.utf8.fromBytes(decryptedBytes);
console.log(decryptedText.trimEnd('\0'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aes-js/3.1.2/index.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you please explain how you encrypted the Hello string?

Comment: @BharatModi By doing a normal AES-128 encryption of the text "Hello" with the given IV and Key, and with PKCS#7 padding. You can do this using any crypto tool and any programming language. I have made a small [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k8jmuvgc/) for you, so you can see how to do it using the aesjs library.