# Angular 9 NgRx - Detected unserializable action on file uploading

Tags: angular, serialization, file-upload, ngrx

I need to upload a file using Ngrx. I don't have to save the file in the Store but I need to pass it between actions, effects and finally services to manage some datas the APIs send me back.

When I choose the file and then click on the upload button I receive the **Error: Detected unserializable action** on the file parameter.

I tried many solutions like parse and stringify, spreading the object and so on but no one worked. The only solution for now is to set strictActionSerializability on false, but *it's not a solution*.

I reproduced the situation on this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-it6q41

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that manage `File` content inside an `NgRx` store is a good practice, however if you want to go in this way, you can retrieve `File` content as `base64` and then pass it to the action :

```js
onSubmit() {
    const file = this.uploadForm.get('file_store').value;
    const signature = file.type;
    const partner_id = this.partner_id;

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = (e) => {
      this.store.dispatch(
        LoadActions.uploadFile({ content: reader.result, signature, partner_id })
      );
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
```

**Note** : here I changed a little your `uploadFile` action signature, with a `content` property in place of `dataForm` to be more clear.

Comment: Thank you @Thierry. This solution solves the problem of the serializability but, unfortunately, I have to send this file to the Google Storage (sorry, I haven't specified this) which doesn't manage the base64 decode. So I receive a Bad image data response. I need to send it as a raw image.

Comment: You can convert it from `base64` to `ArrayBuffer` when you need to send it to backend. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797299/convert-base64-string-to-arraybuffer/21797381 (link updated)

Comment: Tried everything. Converted into base64 the into ArrayBuffer, then Blob and so on. Most of these solutions works, the file arrive and the size is correct, but Google is not able to render the image.

Comment: I had to surrender to this doing some http calls outside of the ngrx flux and just at the end dispatch the final action.