# Unable to load fonts with opentype.js in bare react-native

Tags: react-native

I'm using this function to load a font with opentype.js in a bare react-native app running on Android, but I'm getting the error *"Font could not be loaded"* :

```
const fontLoader = (url) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    opentype.load('fonts/TextMe-Regular.otf', (error, font) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('error on fontLoader:', error);
        reject(error);
      }
      console.log('fontLoader:', font);
      resolve(font);
    });
  });
```

I've checked the folder inside *android > app > src > main > assets > fonts* and the TextMe-Regular.otf is there.
My app structure is *index.js, App > assets > fonts*

EDIT:

I've found a way to load the font from this absolute path:

```
10.0.2.2:8081/assets/assets/fonts/TextMe-Regular.otf
```

but I can't find the relative path.

Comment: Why do you need to load font? Try this `<Text style={{fontsSize: 20, fontFamily: 'TextMe-Regular'}} />`

Comment: @PirShukarullahShah [opentype.js](https://opentype.js.org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my *hacky way* to dinamically load fonts avoiding Expo.
First of all I linked my assets folder, then I've installed the RNFS to read
the font files and used the [_base64ToArrayBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797299/convert-base64-string-to-arraybuffer) function to provide a buffer for opentype.

```
const fontLoader = (url) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const encodedFont = await RNFS.readFileAssets('fonts/TextMe-Regular.otf')
    const bufferedFont = _base64ToArrayBuffer(encodedFont);
    const loadedFont = opentype.parse(bufferedFont);
    resolve(loadedFont);
    });
  });
```