# Blazor to Javascript byte array interop

Tags: javascript, arrays, blazor

I am trying to pass an array of `byte` from Blazor Client to a javascript function:

```
private async void ShowImage()
{
    SelectedImageBytes = await GetImageData();
    if (SelectedImageBytes.Any())
    {
        ReceivedDataLength = SelectedImageBytes.Length;
        //ReceivedDataLength is 131072, which is correct
        JS.InvokeVoidAsync("JS.setImage", SelectedImageBytes, 256, 256);
        
    }

    StateHasChanged();
}
```

On Javascript side:

```
function setImage(data, width, height)
{
    console.log("On Javascript I have received an array of " + data.length);
    //data.length is 174764
    console.log(data);

    //...
}
```

`console.log(data)` outputs the following:

[image]

Which seems to me a base64 string representation of my binary data. According wikipedia the size is incremented approximately by 33% going from byte array to base64 string representation, and this is true for this case: 131072 * 1.33 ~ 174764

My questions then are:

- How to pass and receive a byte array from Blazor (C#) to Javascript without converting it to a string
- If the previous is not possible, what is the best way to convert the base64 string to byte array on Javascript side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I gave it another go:

C#

```
public void CallJsUnMarshalled()
{
    var unmarshalledRuntime = (IJSUnmarshalledRuntime)JS;
    unmarshalledRuntime.InvokeUnmarshalled<byte[], int>("JsFunctions.MyFunctionUnmarshalled", MyBytes);
}
```

Javascript:

```
function MyFunctionUnmarshalled(bytes)
{
    const dataPtr = Blazor.platform.getArrayEntryPtr(bytes, 0, 4);
    const length = Blazor.platform.getArrayLength(bytes);
    var shorts = new Int16Array(Module.HEAPU8.buffer, dataPtr, length);
    return 0;
}
```

`InvokeUnmarshalled` requires a return it appears, therefore `int` in the template arguments. Instead of this probably a reference to the object has to be returned to dispose it. I would appreciate if someone can comment on this (will javascript free that memory when the byte array is not used anymore?).

First tests show an improvement of a factor of 50!

Comment: This worked great, thanks so much! For anyone else that needs to return a string from the javascript function i.e. you have to return a binding to the string like so: `return BINDING.js_string_to_mono_string(url);` This is noted [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0#unmarshalled-javascript-interop-1) and the function name is subject to change in the future.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using the interop service, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0) says:

> InvokeAsync takes an identifier for the JavaScript function that you wish to invoke along with any number of **JSON-serializable** arguments.

So what you observe is the serialization of your byte array into a base64 string, which is the out-of-the-box behavior. So, you are right. I haven't spotted a way to influence the serialization behavior of the JSInterop service.

The Blazer framework in .NET 5 offers you a way to skip the serialization overhead: [IJSUnmarshalledRuntime](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/JSInterop/Microsoft.JSInterop/src/IJSUnmarshalledObjectReference.cs).

But, in my experiments, it can't handle a byte array or any arrays at all.

To answer your second question, have a look at this discussion.

[Convert base64 string to ArrayBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797299/convert-base64-string-to-arraybuffer)

Comment: Looks very promising. Do you have an idea why it is not working?

Comment: I guess that an array is not a native javascript type, unlike numbers or strings. It works fine with an object composed of numbers, strings, and nested objects composed of numbers and strings. :)  
Instead of the array, it seems that a kind of identifier (a number that reminds me a bit of C pointer) is injected into the javascript method. I can imagine that this number with some calls to other javascript methods could lead you near the array.

Comment: I followed your hint of IJSUnmarshalledRuntime and somehow managed it to work, thanks!