# Substitute for Uint8Array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, base64

Since my javascript program is going to upload documents to the server using the FormData object, and the documents are in base64 format, I need to convert a base64 string to a byte array, and this link seems to be the correct one for that:

[Convert base64 string to ArrayBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797299/convert-base64-string-to-arraybuffer):

```
function _base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    var binary_string = window.atob(base64);
    var len = binary_string.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
}
```

Unfortunately, my program depends on an older version of javascript which doesn't define Uint8Array.
Does anyone know if there's a alternative way of accomplishing what I want or if there is an alternative to Uint8Array that I can use?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unluckly it seems that you don't have access to TypedArrays and their buffers, so you can use a simple array.

```js
function _base64ToArray(base64) {
    var binary_string = window.atob(base64);
    var bytes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < binary_string.length; i++) {
        bytes.push(binary_string.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Using an array is it not the same as a buffer, but I hope this can solve your problem anyway.

Comment: Thanks DDomen, but unfortunately I cannot pass the value returned from _base64ToArray to the FormData as I get this:

Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'.

Comment: You need to wrap the array as a Blob befor sending it through your Ajax, just do `request.send(new Blob(_base64ToArray(array)))`

Comment: Also check if [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) is available, you can also substitute Uint8Array with it.

Comment: @HankRearden I saw your edit, you should pass the array directly, and have you also tried to set options of the blob? Maybe like this `new Blob(value2, { type: 'image/png' })`? Otherwise you can build the Blob directly from the `binary_string` argument of the `_base64ToArray`, like `new Blob([ binary_string ], { type: 'image/png' })`. See also [Blob MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob).

Comment: Thanks but when changing the code to 

requestBody.append(parameter.Name, new Blob(value2, { type: 'image/png' }), "hank.png");

the generated file contains something like 

2552162552240167470737001010960960025525...

just an sequence of numbers. I guess that the blob just doesn't work with bytearrays but only with ArrayBuffer and TypesArrays :-(