# Crypto Subtle Decrypt Parameter Not Type "CryptoKey"

Tags: javascript, encryption, subtlecrypto

I'm trying to [decrypt a string using SubtleCrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/encrypt) that was [pre-generated](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption).

Instead of getting decrypted text I'm getting the error: Failed to execute 'decrypt' on 'SubtleCrypto': parameter 2 is not of type 'CryptoKey'.

```
console.log(window.crypto.subtle.decrypt({name:"AES-CBC", iv:""}, "1234567890123456", "i4+WxNH8XYMnAm7RsRkfOw=="));
```

I've tried researching the error but haven't come across anything related to such a basic example. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parameters have the wrong types: IV and data must be passed as [`BufferSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BufferSource), the key as [`CryptoKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CryptoKey), see [`SubtleCrypto.decrypt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/decrypt). A `CryptoKey` is returned by [`SubtleCrypto.importKey()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/importKey), which is used to import the key.

WebCrypto API (as low level API) does not provide support for data conversion, e.g. Base64 encoded data or strings to `BufferSource`, so other helper methods must be used for this.

The following code decrypts the ciphertext:

```js
var keyData = str2ab("1234567890123456");
var iv = new Uint8Array(16).buffer;
var ciphertext = b642ab("i4+WxNH8XYMnAm7RsRkfOw==");

(async () => {
  var decrypted = await decrypt();
  var decryptedStr = new TextDecoder().decode(decrypted);
  console.log(decryptedStr);
})();

async function decrypt() {
  var key = await importKey();
  try {
    return await crypto.subtle.decrypt(
      { name: "AES-CBC", iv: iv },
      key,
      ciphertext
    );
  } catch (ex) {
    console.error("Error: Name: ", ex.name, ", Message: ", ex.message);
  }
}

async function importKey() {
  var key = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "raw",
    keyData,
    { name: "AES-CBC" },
    true,
    ["decrypt", "encrypt"]
  );
  return key;
}

// Helper -----------------------------------------------

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/11058858
function str2ab(str) {
  const buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
  const bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return buf;
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/21797381/9014097
function b642ab(base64) {
  var binary_string = window.atob(base64);
  var len = binary_string.length;
  var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return bytes.buffer;
}
```