# I want to decompress a GZIP string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, gzip, pako

I have this GZIPed string: `H4sIAAAAAAAA//NIzcnJVyguSUzOzi9LLUrLyS/XUSjJSMzLLlZIyy9SSMwpT6wsVshIzSnIzEtXBACs78K6LwAAAA==`

I created that with this website: http://www.txtwizard.net/compression

I have tried using [pako](http://nodeca.github.io/pako/) to ungzip it.

```
import { ungzip } from 'pako';

const textEncoder = new TextEncoder();
const gzipedData = textEncoder.encode("H4sIAAAAAAAA//NIzcnJVyguSUzOzi9LLUrLyS/XUSjJSMzLLlZIyy9SSMwpT6wsVshIzSnIzEtXBACs78K6LwAAAA==");
console.log('gzipeddata', gzipedData);
const ungzipedData = ungzip(gzipedData);
console.log('ungziped data', ungzipedData);
```

The issue is that Pako throws the error: `incorrect header check`

What am I missing here?

[A JSbin](https://jsbin.com/nubepajota/edit?html,css,js,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"H4sIAAAAAAAA//NIzcnJVyguSUzOzi9LLUrLyS/XUSjJSMzLLlZIyy9SSMwpT6wsVshIzSnIzEtXBACs78K6LwAAAA=="` is a base64 encoded string, you first need to decode that into a buffer.

`textEncoder.encode` just encodes that base64 encoded string into a byte stream.

How to do that depend on whether you are in a browser or on nodejs.

### node.js version

To convert the unzipped data to a string you further have use `new TextDecoder().decode()`

For node you will use [`Buffer.from(string, 'base64')`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_static_method_buffer_from_string_encoding) to decode the base64 encoded string:

```
import { ungzip } from 'pako';

// decode the base64 encoded data
const gzipedData = Buffer.from("H4sIAAAAAAAA//NIzcnJVyguSUzOzi9LLUrLyS/XUSjJSMzLLlZIyy9SSMwpT6wsVshIzSnIzEtXBACs78K6LwAAAA==", "base64");

console.log('gzipeddata', gzipedData);
const ungzipedData = ungzip(gzipedData);


console.log('ungziped data', new TextDecoder().decode(ungzipedData));
```

### browser version

In the browser, you have to use [`atob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/atob), and you need to convert the decoded data to an `Uint8Array` using e.g.  [`Uint8Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/from).

The conversion I used was taken from [Convert base64 string to ArrayBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797299/convert-base64-string-to-arraybuffer), you might need to verify if that really works in all cases.

```js
// decode the base64 encoded data
const gezipedData = atob("H4sIAAAAAAAA//NIzcnJVyguSUzOzi9LLUrLyS/XUSjJSMzLLlZIyy9SSMwpT6wsVshIzSnIzEtXBACs78K6LwAAAA==")
const gzipedDataArray = Uint8Array.from(gezipedData, c => c.charCodeAt(0))

console.log('gzipeddata', gzipedDataArray);
const ungzipedData = pako.ungzip(gzipedDataArray);


console.log('ungziped data', new TextDecoder().decode(ungzipedData));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pako/2.0.4/pako.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Now I'm getting: `invalid stored block lengths`

Comment: @petur where do you run that code (browser or node, what version of node or which browser). The first code snipped runs fine in `node` and the second one shows the correct output when I run it in the browser.

Comment: I'm running it in the browser. ! I just replaced `Buffer.from` with `atob`, didn't realize I had to do both `atob` and `Uint8Array.from`

Thanks!

Comment: @petur The first one is the node version (node has `Buffer.from`). the second on is for the browser, there only `atob` exists and the result that call is not compatible with `pako` you need to convert it to an `Uint8Array` first,

Answer (score 1):

This string is base64-encoded.

You first need to decode it to a buffer:

```js
const gzippedString = 'H4sIAAAAAAAA//NIzcnJVyguSUzOzi9LLUrLyS/XUSjJSMzLLlZIyy9SSMwpT6wsVshIzSnIzEtXBACs78K6LwAAAA==';
const gzippedBuffer = new Buffer(gzippedString, 'base64');
```

Then you can un(g)zip it:

```js
const unzippedBuffer = ungzip(gzippedBuffer);
```

The result on `ungzip` is a `Unit8Array`. If you want to convert it back to a string you'll need to decode it again:

```js
const unzippedString = new TextDecoder('utf8').decode(unzipped);
```