# Efficient way to convert base64 string to ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, base64, arraybuffer

Given a `base64` string, what is the safest and most efficient way to create an `ArrayBuffer`. Specifically a typeless array buffer in pure modern JavaScript.

The first SO result is [this question from 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797299/convert-base64-string-to-arraybuffer). The accepted answer is

```
function _base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    var binary_string = window.atob(base64);
    var len = binary_string.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
}
```

It already assumes a type and there are comments which suggest that this is not always correct.

Is this still the best solution today? Do we have to iterate over all elements in a for loop? Is there a better and more efficient way using vanilla JS where we can pass a `blob` of the string?

An example problem is processing a [GLTF buffer](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Tutorials/blob/master/gltfTutorial/gltfTutorial_005_BuffersBufferViewsAccessors.md) which is provided as a `base64` encoded string:

```
let str = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,AAABAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIA/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAPwAAAAA=';
```

This has two separate views of scalar (unsigned short) and `vec3` (float) data, requiring further processing.

[edit]

So the most popular answer is not of use here as it creates a `TypedArray` but the data in the `base64` string does not represent a homogenous data set.

Comment: Your last line makes no sense at all.  Is that left over from another post?  Nowhere in your question is there anything about views, unsigned short, vec3 or float, and none of those things would seem to be Javascript concepts.

Comment: @TimRoberts The last line is to add context. The issue is that the most popular answer creates a `Uint8Array` and not a typeless `ArrayBuffer` on which further operations can be made. It's really to iterate that I don't want a `TypedArray` because that will lock you into a single view of the binary data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your `str` is a `data:uri`, you might use `fetch`:

```js
let str = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,AAABAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIA/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAPwAAAAA=';

fetch(str)
  .then(b => b.arrayBuffer())
  .then(buff => console.log( new Int8Array(buff) /* just for a view purpose */ ))
  .catch(e => console.log(e))
```

Comment: Is the `.then(r => r.blob())` step necessary? Can we use `arrayBuffer()` immediately?

Comment: Fetch response seems to have an `arrayBuffer()` method for convenience. Is there a difference between these two? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/arrayBuffer

Comment: @dubious, you're right! No need to `blob()`