# Decode Base64 with UCS-2 Encoding

Tags: javascript, unicode, base64

I want to decode the Base64 result of MS-SQL Server in javascript, but I can't find a true solution. I know SQL Server uses UCS-2 encoding, and I have to use the same encoding to decode in javascript.

For example, for `MwZEBicGRQY=` the encoded result must be `سلام`.

Do you have any solution to decode that using javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first [decode your base64 data into an Uint8Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797299/convert-base64-string-to-arraybuffer), and then [read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder) the resulting data as UTF-16:

```js
const base64_string = "MwZEBicGRQY";
// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/41106346/3702797
// may not be bullet-proof
const arr = Uint8Array.from(atob(base64_string), c => c.charCodeAt(0))
const decoded = new TextDecoder("UTF-16").decode(arr);

console.log(decoded);
```