# React Native Expo Image Picker Image How to Send as Postman Binary File

Tags: javascript, react-native, file-upload, expo, expo-image-picker

Im using Expo for React Native and it's Image Picker. I would like to send my image file that I get from my phone as binary like I send in Postman as in the picture below.

[image]

Im using Axios for API operations.

I tried to send the base64 data or fetch the image from it's uri and send it's blob. Both none of them worked.

This is my axios post request template.

```
 post: async (url, data) => {
    const token = await getToken("token")
    const res = await instance(token).post(url, data).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.response)
      return error.response.data.message;
    });
    console.log(res.data)
    return res.data;
  },
```

And this is my Imagepicker code

```
const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsMultipleSelection: false,
      aspect: [4, 2],
      base64: true,
    });

    if (!result.canceled) { 
        dispatch(authActions.uploadProfileImageRequest(result.assets[0].base64))
   
    }


  };
```

How can I accomplish to send data file as I did in Postman?

Comment: check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70891840/send-image-as-raw-data-axios-react-native