# Base64 encoding bytes in python, decoding in javascript doesn't return the original bytes

Tags: javascript, python, base64, byte

I base64 encoded bytes in python:

```py
import base64
base64.b64encode(b"\xac\xd1%=\xdd\xe7\x18\x8f\xbcDrz\xa3\x8a\xac\x8dT\x88\t\xcf7\no\xfb\xa2\x97CI\x85\xe4:\xf2/\xd8a\xb5\xd2\x82\xa8\xce\x02Df\xd0?\x06re>\xb0\x94];~\xff\x00cV\xb5\xe3\xe8\xd1\xa0n").decode("utf-8")
# "rNElPd3nGI+8RHJ6o4qsjVSICc83Cm/7opdDSYXkOvIv2GG10oKozgJEZtA/BnJlPrCUXTt+/wBjVrXj6NGgbg=="
```

---

But when I am trying to decode it back to bytes in javascript:

```js
atob("rNElPd3nGI+8RHJ6o4qsjVSICc83Cm/7opdDSYXkOvIv2GG10oKozgJEZtA/BnJlPrCUXTt+/wBjVrXj6NGgbg==")
// "¬Ñ%=Ýç\x18\x8F¼Drz£\x8A¬\x8DT\x88\tÏ7\noû¢\x97CI\x85ä:ò/ØaµÒ\x82¨Î\x02DfÐ?\x06re>°\x94];~ÿ\x00cVµãèÑ n"
```

I don't get the original bytes.
How can I decode it with javascript and get the original bytes as a string?

Comment: I can't reproduce your output of `b64encode()`.

Comment: I accidently pasted the wrong thing, I fixed it

Comment: Everything is okay with `atob()` output, it's equal to source you've encoded using python.

Comment: STRING "¬Ñ%=Ýç\x18\x8F¼Drz£\x8A¬\x8DT\x88\tÏ7\noû¢\x97CI\x85ä:ò/ØaµÒ\x82¨Î\x02DfÐ?\x06re>°\x94];~ÿ\x00cVµãèÑ" is not equal to STRING "\xac\xd1%=\xdd\xe7\x18\x8f\xbcDrz\xa3\x8a\xac\x8dT\x88\t\xcf7\no\xfb\xa2\x97CI\x85\xe4:\xf2/\xd8a\xb5\xd2\x82\xa8\xce\x02Df\xd0?\x06re>\xb0\x94];~\xff\x00cV\xb5\xe3\xe8\xd1\xa0n." It's the same bytes, but I don't want javascript to translate it to actual text, I need it to be the bytes as a string.

Comment: You can't choose how built-in functions work, but you definitely can either make own implementation of base64 decode which will return array or convert return of `atob()` into array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert base64 string to ArrayBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797299/convert-base64-string-to-arraybuffer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`atob` will try decoding the bytes as text, instead of encoding the bytes into something like the `b'...'` in Python.

You asked: `How can I decode it with javascript and get the original bytes as a string?` But I believe, you should just use the bytes rather than convert it to a string.

So I tried [my base-64 decoding tool](https://tools.nololiyt.top/tools/39f09c93-0d5b-ca7c-cdc8-185b00aec141.html). I think the byte array it returns meets your requirement (as `ac` does mean `172`): `[172, 209, 37, 61, 221, 231, 24, 143, 188, 68, 114, 122, 163, 138, 172, 141, 84, 136, 9, 207, 55, 10, 111, 251, 162, 151, 67, 73, 133, 228, 58, 242, 47, 216, 97, 181, 210, 130, 168, 206, 2, 68, 102, 208, 63, 6, 114, 101, 62, 176, 148, 93, 59, 126, 255, 0, 99, 86, 181, 227, 232, 209, 160, 110]`.

In the tool I used the package [`js-base64`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-base64) to decode it. But it was developed years ago, I don't know whether there are better solutions now.