# Parse Universal Binary JSON token in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, encryption, vuejs2, token, decode

## Universal Binary JSON

I'm on a vue.js v2 project. I need to parse a token after logged in. It is not a JWT token. It's a [Ubjson](https://ubjson.org/) token. I am using javascript, and I can't find any Ubjson token decoder anywhere.

If you know how to decode it, please help me out.

---

## I've tried

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shelacek/ubjson

```
import { Ubjson } from '@shelacek/ubjson'



const obj = Ubjson.decode(token)
console.log(obj) //undefined
```

## Result

```
undefined
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a [UBJSON encoder/decoder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shelacek/ubjson) on NPM

See [code-8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71961165/3330981)'s answer

---

---

Try something like this:

See in action [https://runkit.com/embed/3ngoupnl0unj]=

```js
const ubjson = require('@shelacek/ubjson');
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/62364519/3330981
function base64ToBytesArr(str) {
  const abc = [..."ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"]; // base64 alphabet
  let result = [];
  for(let i=0; i<str.length/4; i++) {
    let chunk = [...str.slice(4*i,4*i+4)]
    let bin = chunk.map(x=> abc.indexOf(x).toString(2).padStart(6,0)).join(''); 
    let bytes = bin.match(/.{1,8}/g).map(x=> +('0b'+x));
    result.push(...bytes.slice(0,3 - (str[4*i+2]=="=") - (str[4*i+3]=="=")));
  }
  return result;
}
const token = "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"
const obj = ubjson.decode(base64ToBytesArr(token));
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Right now my project using `yarn`, if I run this `npm install --save @shelacek/ubjson` ... will it messed up ?

Comment: Just use the yarn equivalent.

Comment: https://runkit.com/embed/lrfjcwq0yaxw - please check out my solution... no need to include that *base64ToBytesArr*

Comment: @code-8 very cool. Buffer was not working in my browser for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

These solutions also work for me with fewer lines of code.

```
var ubjson = require("@shelacek/ubjson")

const token = '123***XYZ'

const buffer = Buffer.from(token, 'base64')
const obj = ubjson.decode(buffer)
console.log(obj)
```