# Convert string to Uint8Array

Tags: javascript

I have string like below

```
b/dWBWBYDdE2A5Uh
```

I want to convert to:

```
Uint8Array(12) [111, 247, 86, 5, 96, 88, 13, 209, 54, 3, 149, 33, buffer: ArrayBuffer(12), byteLength: 12, byteOffset: 0, length: 12, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): 'Uint8Array']
```

So I tried something like below

```
new TextEncoder("utf-8").encode("b/dWBWBYDdE2A5Uh");
```

But I get

```
Uint8Array(16) [98, 47, 100, 87, 66, 87, 66, 89, 68, 100, 69, 50, 65, 53, 85, 104, buffer: ArrayBuffer(16), byteLength: 16, byteOffset: 0, length: 16, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): 'Uint8Array'] ,
```

I believe this string is encrypted. This was done by third party website, so I am trying to decode it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `b/dWBWBYDdE2A5Uh` is the base-64 encoded version of the given 12 bytes of binary data. You can decode base-64 with `atob`, but it gives you a string and not an `Uint8Array`. Each character in the string represents one byte.

There is no built-in function to convert this string to an `Uint8Array`, but we can do it, as adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41106346/14637):

```
>> Uint8Array.from(atob('b/dWBWBYDdE2A5Uh'), c => c.charCodeAt(0))
Uint8Array(12) [ 111, 247, 86, 5, 96, 88, 13, 209, 54, 3, … ]
```