# How to convert image from base64 to array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, base64

I have got a image in my javascript code which is in base64 format as given below:

```
Img=image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSK.......
```

Now I want to convert this image into array using javascript.

Comment: Why into an array?

Comment: Do you possibly mean a [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData)?

Comment: Hi, could you be more specific please? Would you like to convert the Base64 image to a Uint8Array, or an ArrayBuffer, or another element like Blob or Buffer ?

Comment: You want to add it to an array or convert it to an array? Also you don't convert a String to an array you just create an array with the string as its first element.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @LucasPaixão i need to convert into uint8array

Comment: @parker Hi, I posted an answer, if it's incomplete or unsatisfactory, please comment so I can edit it :)

Comment: @parker Any questions, please comment so I can edit my answer, I wish you success on your journey :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Try this:

---

```
function base64ToUint8Array(base64) {
    const binary = atob(base64);
    const len = binary.length;
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++)
        bytes[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
    return bytes;
}

base64ToUint8Array(YourBase64String)
```

#### Explanation

---

Well it's pretty straightforward,

1. First we decode the base64 string (atob),
2. then we create new array
   of 8-bit unsigned integers with the same length as the decoded
   string. (Uint8Array)
3. After that we iterate the string and populate
   the array with Unicode value of each character in the string.

#### Example:

---

```js
function base64ToUint8Array(base64) {
    const binary = atob(base64);
    const len = binary.length;
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++)
        bytes[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
    return bytes;
}

const image = `Img=image/jpeg;base64,T25seUV4YW1wbGU=`
const base64 = image.split('base64,')[1]
console.log(base64ToUint8Array(base64))
```

Reference: [Convert base64 string to ArrayBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797299/convert-base64-string-to-arraybuffer)

#### Remarks

---

If you want to return an `ArrayBuffer` instead of a `Uint8Array`, you should ***return*** `bytes.buffer` instead of `bytes`

Answer (score 2):

Do you possibly mean a [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData)? it's a 1d array where each 4 consecutive numbers (bytes?) represent (r,g,b,a) with values 0..255

```js
var str = "data:image/png;base64,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"


var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var image = new Image()
image.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
  console.log(imageData)
}
image.src = str;
document.body.appendChild(canvas)
```