# How do I deserialize a protobuf string in js sent from a python backend?

Tags: javascript, python, protocol-buffers

I have a Flask server that sends a serialized protocol buffer message. I've de-serialized this message in a few environments successfully, including a C++ client. However, when I attempt to de-serialize my message in js, nothing works. I am using [protobuf.js](https://github.com/protobufjs). According to the documentation, I think I am doing it correctly.

Here is the protobuff file `vtkMessage.proto`:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package vtkMessage;

message hash_element {
  string name = 1;
  repeated float v = 2;
}

message hash {
  repeated hash_element elem = 1;
}

message vtkMsg {
  repeated int32 tris=1;
  repeated float verts=2;
  hash vals=3;
}
```

Here is my Flask server `test.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, request
import vtkMessage_pb2

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='')

@app.route('/test',methods = ['POST'])
def test():
  data = request.get_json()
  ret = vtkMessage_pb2.vtkMsg()
  ret.tris.extend([1,2,3])
  ret.verts.extend([0.45,0.35,0.11, 0.66,0.78,0.23, 0.11,0.01,0.14])
  a = ret.vals.elem.add()
  a.name = 'test1'
  a.v.extend([0.1, 0.2])
  a = ret.vals.elem.add()
  a.name = 'test2'
  a.v.extend([0.3, 0.5])
  print(ret)
  return ret.SerializeToString() # this decodes successfully when I use C++

@app.route('/protoTest')
def protoTest():
  return render_template('protoTest.html')
```

Here is `templates/protoTest.html`:

```
<html>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/protobufjs@7.2.5/dist/protobuf.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = main;

    function main() {
      var dat = JSON.stringify({
        step: 0,
        frames: 1,
        fname: "openfoam.vtk"
      });
      protobuf.load('vtkMessage.proto', function(err,root) {
        window.vtkMsg = root.lookupType("vtkMessage.vtkMsg");
        var proto_obj = {};

        $.ajax({
          url:'/test',
          data: dat,
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
          async: false,
          success: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
            var buffer = new TextEncoder("utf-8").encode(res);
            proto_obj = vtkMsg.decode(buffer); // WHY IS THIS FAILING???
            console.log(proto_obj);
          },
          error: function(res) {
            console.error(res);  // sometimes this also happens
          }
        });

        console.log(proto_obj);

      });
    }
  </script>

  <body>
     <h1>Protobuf test, view in console</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

To get the `vtkMessage_pb2.py` you will need to run:
`protoc -I=. --python_out=. vtkMessage.proto`

I suspect that `var buffer = new TextEncoder("utf-8").encode(res);` is incorrect, but I don't see any documentation on how this should be done. Also, my fear is that flask and/or jquery does something funky in handling the `POST` request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is reasonable to want to ship Protobuf serialized messages using RESTful mechanisms as you're trying to do but, it's unclear to me why you wouldn't just use pure JSON and REST in this case.

That said, your code attempts to mix incorrectly JSON (you `POST` JSON to the `test` method (which is then discarded) and you attempt to return binary (invalid JSON) from the server.

I suspect (but don't show here) that it would be possible to post `application/grpc` (binary) content to a server.

Instead, I show an approach that combines JSON w/ Protobuf binary messages. In order to ship a Protobuf binary message, you must base64-encode it.

```
{
  data: "{base64-encoded serialized Protobuf message}"
}
```

I'm not very familiar with Flask nor with JavaScript so the following code would benefit from improvement but it works:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify, render_template, request

import base64
import vtkMessage_pb2

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='')

@app.route('/test',methods = ['POST'])
def test():
  # Discard !?
  data = request.get_json()

  msg = vtkMessage_pb2.vtkMsg()
  msg.tris.extend([1,2,3])
  msg.verts.extend([0.45,0.35,0.11, 0.66,0.78,0.23, 0.11,0.01,0.14])
  a = msg.vals.elem.add()
  a.name = 'test1'
  a.v.extend([0.1, 0.2])
  a = msg.vals.elem.add()
  a.name = 'test2'
  a.v.extend([0.3, 0.5])
  print(msg)

  # Convert Protobuf message to binary string
  b = msg.SerializeToString()

  # Base64 encode it to bundle as JSON
  data = base64.b64encode(b).decode("ascii")

  # Return JSON message
  return jsonify({"data": data})

@app.route('/protoTest')
def protoTest():
  return render_template('protoTest.html')
```

And:

```
<html>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/protobufjs@7.2.5/dist/protobuf.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = main;

    // Base64 decode and return Uint8Array
    // See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21797381/609290
    function base64ToBytes(base64) {
      var binaryString = atob(base64);
      var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryString.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < binaryString.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      return bytes;
    }

    function main() {
      // POSTed but ignored by the server
      var data = JSON.stringify({
        step: 0,
        frames: 1,
        fname: "openfoam.vtk"
      });
      protobuf.load('vtkMessage.proto', function(err,root) {
        window.vtkMsg = root.lookupType("vtkMessage.vtkMsg");
        var proto_obj = {};

        $.ajax({
          url:'/test',
          data: data,
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
          async: false,
          success: function(res) {
            // JSON response {"data":...}
            console.log(res);
            // Extract the Protobuf binary data
            b = base64ToBytes(res.data);
            // Deserialize the message
            msg = vtkMsg.decode(b);
            console.log(msg);
          },
          error: function(res) {
            console.error(res);
          }
        });

        console.log(msg);

      });
    }
  </script>

  <body>
     <h1>Protobuf test, view in console</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

The console output includes the base64-encoded message:

```
{
    "data": "CgMBAgMSJGZm5j4zM7M+rkfhPcP1KD8Urkc/H4VrPq5H4T0K1yM8KVwPPhomChEKBXRlc3QxEgjNzMw9zcxMPgoRCgV0ZXN0MhIImpmZPgAAAD8="
}
```

You can use e.g. Bash to extract the hex content:

```bash
printf "CgMBAgMSJGZm5j4zM7M+rkfhPcP1KD8Urkc/H4VrPq5H4T0K1yM8KVwPPhomChEKBXRlc3QxEgjN
zMw9zcxMPgoRCgV0ZXN0MhIImpmZPgAAAD8=" \
| base64 --decode \
| xxd -c 128 -g 128
```

```
0a0301020312246666e63e3333b33eae47e13dc3f5283f14ae473f1f856b3eae47e13d0ad7233c295c0f3e1a260a110a0574657374311208cdcccc3dcdcc4c3e0a110a05746573743212089a99993e0000003f
```

You can paste this into e.g. [Protobuf Decoder](https://protobuf-decoder.netlify.app/) to confirm that it is correct.

And if you browse `localhost:5000/protoTest`, you should see the `vtkMsg` correctly recreated by the JavaScript client.

Comment: "it's unclear to me why you wouldn't just use pure JSON and REST in this case." This is actually just a test application for debugging. JSON can't be used, these files become too large to serialize and send (it's talking to a zmq+mpi+C++ backend that runs HPC simulations). This is a real-time simulation of a complex 3D mesh. I am polling the frames with POST (fast enough), websockets is probably more appropriate, but I have the same issue with de-serializing.

Comment: That makes sense. Perhaps consider using gRPC? If you're using Protobufs for the Message content, it's not too much of a stretch to add Services|Methods too. No need to reply.

Answer (score 0):

**Do you specifically need to parse the serialized message in js**???
If yess? then I believe [DazWilkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/609290/dazwilkin)'s solution would work.

And ignore the rest of the answer

Else if you just want to send data to js, then you can simplify your program by doing all the protobuf serialization and parsing within python itself.

These updates in your code

```py
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson, ParseDict

@app.route('/test',methods = ['POST'])
def test():
  data = request.get_json()
  ret = vtkMessage_pb2.vtkMsg()
  ret = ParseDict(dict(
    tris = [1,2,3],
    verts = [0.45,0.35,0.11, 0.66,0.78,0.23, 0.11,0.01,0.14],
    vals = dict(elem = [dict(name = 'test1', v = [0.1, 0.2]), dict(name = 'test2', v = [0.3, 0.5])])
  ),
  ret)
  print(ret)
#   return ret.SerializeToString() # this decodes successfully when I use C++
  return MessageToJson(ret)
```

and

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = main;

    function main() {
      var dat = JSON.stringify({
        step: 0,
        frames: 1,
        fname: "openfoam.vtk"
      });
      protobuf.load('vtkMessage.proto', function(err,root) {
        window.vtkMsg = root.lookupType("vtkMessage.vtkMsg");
        var proto_obj = {};

        $.ajax({
          url:'/test',
          data: dat,
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
          async: false,
          success: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
            // var buffer = new TextEncoder("utf-8").encode(res);
            // proto_obj = vtkMsg.decode(buffer); // WHY IS THIS FAILING??? 
            // console.log(proto_obj);
          },
          error: function(res) {
            console.error(res);  // sometimes this also happens
          }
        });

        console.log(proto_obj);

      });
    }
  </script>
```

and there is beautiful json dump in my console log