# encodeURIComponent appears to add a character to my string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, character-encoding, encodeuricomponent

`jQuery.ajax()` is doing something weird when escaping my data.

For example, if I send the request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'somethinguninteresting',
    data: {
        name: 'Ihave¬aweirdcharacter';
    }
});
```

then investigate the XHR in Chrome devtools, it shows the "Request Payload" as `name=Ihave%C2%ACaweirdcharacter`

Now, I've figured out that:

```
'¬'.charCodeAt(0) === 172
```

and that 172 is `AC` in hexadecimal.

Working backwards, `C2` (the "extra" character being prepended) in hexadecimal is 194 in decimal, and

```
String.fromCharCode(194) === 'Â'
```

### My Question:

Why does

```
encodeURIComponent('¬')
```

return `'%C2%AC'`, which would *appear* to be the result of calling

```
encodeURIComponent('Â¬')
```

(which itself returns `'%C3%82%C2%AC'`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although JavaScript uses UTF-16 (or UCS-2) internally, it performs URI encoding based on UTF-8.

The ordinal value of 172 is encoded in two bytes, because it can no longer be represented by ASCII; two-byte encoding in UTF-8 is done this way:

```
110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
```

In the place of `x` we fill in the binary representation of 172, which is 10101100:

```
11000010 10101100 = C2AC
   ^^^
   pad
```

This outcome is then percent encoded to finally form `%C2%AC` which is what you saw in the request payload.

Comment: Aaah - so it's actually just a -coincidence- that the second byte happens to be 172 in binary!  That was *really* throwing me off.  Thank you for your explanation.  Am I correct in thinking that your "^^^ pad" is off by one character?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan Eh yeah, it's off .. ascii art mistake ;-)

Comment: Very nice, far easier to understand when its described visually like that.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Url encoding (or [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)), encodes unicode characters using [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). UTF-8 encodes characters with varying numbers of bytes. The ¬ character is encoded in UTF-8 as `C2 AC`.

The `charCodeAt` method does not handle multi-byte sequences. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18729931/4231110 for more details on how to use charCodeAt to encode a string with UTF-8.

In short, `%C2%AC` is the correct percent encoding of ¬. This can be demonstrated by running

```
decodeURIComponent('%C2%AC') // '¬'
```

Comment: `C2 AC` is hexadecimal or base16 encoded, not UTF-8.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I don't follow. The unicode character is [U+00AC](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ac/index.htm) which is encoded in UTF-8 as the hexadecimal string C2AC, or the binary sequence 1100001010101100 if you prefer that.

Comment: The transformation of `¬` to `%C2%AC` is technically base16 encoding. `C2 AC` is the hexadecimal representation of the `¬` in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: `%C2%AC` is the direct utf8 encoding of `¬` http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp i dont understand why is it confusing or `weird`

Comment: That seems like a *massive* amount of mucking around to send a plain text string from a browser to server via AJAX, the likes of which don't appear in any similar javascript I've seen/read.  What value would I send as `data.name` in the above example to get the expected result (ie sending the string correctly)?

Comment: You don't need to do anything at all. The point is that `%C2%AC` *is* the correct encoding.