# String encoding when constructing a Blob

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8

I know that JavaScript strings [are usually](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding) encoded [with an encoding taking at least two bytes per character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715980/javascript-strings-utf-16-vs-ucs-2) (UTF-16 or UCS-2).

However, when constructing a Blob, a different encoding appears to be used because when I read it as `ArrayBuffer`, the length of the returned buffer is 3 for an Euro sign.

```
var b = new Blob(['€']);
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#blob), it is **UTF-8** encoded.

Demo:

```js
// Create a Blob with an Euro-char (U+20AC)
var b = new Blob(['€']);
var fr = new FileReader();

fr.onload = function() {
  ua = new Uint8Array(fr.result);
  // This will log "3|226|130|172"
  //                  E2  82  AC
  // In UTF-16, it would be only 2 bytes long
  console.log(
    fr.result.byteLength + '|' + 
    ua[0]  + '|' + 
    ua[1] + '|' + 
    ua[2] + ''
  );
};
fr.readAsArrayBuffer(b);
```

Play with that on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uowf8qws/).