# How to get java code - String.getBytes("UTF-8"); similar output in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

java code --

```
String plainText = "thisismyplaintext";
byte[] bytes = plainText.getBytes("UTF-8");

System.out.println(bytes);
// Output - [B@3cd1a2f1
```

I am trying to do the same thing in javascript but I am always getting absolutely different output like example - `[11, 12, 14, 16]`.

I have tried everything from different stackoverfow answers but nothing is working similar to this java code.

Please help me to achieve the same thing in javascript and to get similar output.

Comment: Please keep in mind that Java and JavaScript are not the same programming language and correct the tags.

Comment: @JayJamesJay I think OP is aware of this. OP wants to translate the Java code to Javascript code

Comment: @Nick Parsons You're right, my mistake.

Comment: The output of java Byte arrays is the object reference. Read about object.toString(). You will not be able to get this in JavaScript.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve same thing in  Node.js. Sorry I have not mentioned that I am actually using Node.js I know Node.js is also javascript but there's lot's of library available.

Comment: Even so, this is clearly a javascript problem.  The `java` tag is inappropriate.  Hint: think about what the purpose of tags is: to make it easier for *other* people to find Q&A's that are relevant to them.   People trying to solve a problem like this will be looking for javascript Q&A's not java Q&A's.

Comment: @Stephen. Ok I just mentioned Java because Java code is included.

Comment: Yes, but it is not **about** Java.

Comment: The other problem is that you haven't explained what output you actually want to be produced.   (Especially since that Java output is probably bogus ... for most purposes.)  What are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: @Stephen Please check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57123473/aes-128-cbc-encrytion-decryption-using-crypto-in-node-js-not-giving-proper-resul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[B@3cd1a2f1` is not the result you are after. `[B@3cd1a2f1` represents the class type (`[B`) of your array of bytes and the hex representation of your array's hash. You need to instead print the array contents, which can be done using `Arrays.toString()`:

```
String plainText = "thisismyplaintext";
byte[] bytes = plainText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

This will give the array:

```
[116, 104, 105, 115, 105, 115, 109, 121, 112, 108, 97, 105, 110, 116, 101, 120, 116]
```

This you can get the same result in Javascript using the following:

```js
const str = "thisismyplaintext";
const utf8 = unescape(encodeURIComponent(str));
const arr = [...utf8].map(c => c.charCodeAt(0));
console.log(arr);
```

<sup>- Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18729536/5648954) for byte array algorithm</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was unaware of that what is happening in that java code.