# How to convert decimal number into Hex UTF-8 bytes

Tags: javascript, utf-8, converters

[Picture of already converted code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0BWV.png)

I'm stuck at converting a decimal number to Hex UTF-8 bytes. Can anyone help me out by explaining how do you convert it or what formula is used to convert it? If any of you have a Javascript code that already does that, it will help.

Example: 210 (decimal number) converts to C3 92 (UTF-8 bytes)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert UTF8 string to byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729405/how-to-convert-utf8-string-to-byte-array)

Comment: Do no include pictures. Copy the text in the question.