# Calculate the accurate size in bytes of a string in k6

Tags: k6

k6 doesn’t provide a built-in way to measure byte size of a string in UTF-8 encoding directly like Buffer, it’s not able to provide an accurate size calculation. I had a workaround by assuming most characters with 1-2bytes, but it’s not precise especially when a string contains different language characters.
Anyone know if there is a better way to measure size in byte accurately?

Answer (score 0):

It's anything but efficient, but you can encode to base64, then [decode as ArrayBuffer](https://k6.io/docs/javascript-api/k6-encoding/b64decode/) and query the length:

```
const str = '';
console.log(new Uint8Array(encoding.b64decode(encoding.b64encode(str))).length); // 4
```

Also see [How to convert UTF8 string to byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729405/how-to-convert-utf8-string-to-byte-array)