# I don't understand the string to byte aspect of computing/javascript

Tags: javascript, string, byte

After two years coming back to this/another topic where I see people discussing the same; I still don't understand what is going on.

following this SO post:

[String length in bytes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515869/string-length-in-bytes-in-javascript)

> I want to understand this part of javascript! I am also interested in calculating the kb size of a bitcoin transaction before I push it to the blockchain. The more important of the two though is that I finally understand what these users are doing because its come up more than once and I just don't get it!

I've tried three of the functions outlined as answers but they all seem to do nothing more than return the string.length whereas I would expect them to return a different value (the overhead of the string in bytes/kilobytes/megabytes)

```
function byteCount(s) {
    return encodeURI(s).split(/%..|./).length - 1;
    }

console.log(byteCount('hello'),'hello'.length);//5,5


function getLengthInBytes(str) {
    var b = str.match(/[^\x00-\xff]/g);
    return (str.length + (!b ? 0: b.length)); 
    }

console.log(getLengthInBytes('hello'),'hello'.length);//5,5


console.log((new TextEncoder('utf-8').encode('hello')).length,'hello'.length);//5,5
```

It's annoying that this makes no sense to me! Clearly these people would not be talking about how to get something that they can easily get with string.length **so what are they trying and succeeding in returning?**

Should the string instead be binary? (like so: [How to convert text to binary code in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430633/how-to-convert-text-to-binary-code-in-javascript))

Comment: There are some special chars that take more than one byte of space. Try "Äpfel". The wikipedia article about UTF describes how this work

Comment: Jup i wrote it as an answer

Comment: JavaScript uses UCS-2, which is the standard that became Unicode 1.1 and only allowed up 16bit (two byte) encoding.  Recent versions of Unicode can actually use *seven* bytes per character.    https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of different signs in the world.
They dont fit in one byte of data. Thats why some chars use more than one byte of data. 
Some examples: "Äüöôś"

Comment: Note: Internally JavaScript uses two-bytes per character, not one.  That lets it use UTF-16...

Comment: Nice to know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are testing with the base ascii characters (well, they are utf8, but you can think of them a little like ascii and these characters work very similarly in both encodings).  Try with an extended character.

```js
console.log((new TextEncoder('utf-8').encode('')).length, ''.length);
```