# Generating JWT tokens

Tags: javascript, jwt, jitsi, jitsi-meet

Could anyone provide me an example for generating jwt tokens with three headers given as (alg, kid, typ) that has the format:

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "vpaas-magic-cookie-1fc542a3e4414a44b2611668195e2bfe/4f4910",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

under https://developer.8x8.com/jaas/docs/api-keys-jwt.

Jwt tokens get expired with a time limit of few hours so I am trying to find a way to generate the token in my code itself.

At the end, my javascript looks like this, where I add the jwt token inside the options list for authentication.

```
var options = {
                roomName: "vpaas-magic-cookie-secretKey/Room123",
                jwt: 'JWTTOKEN',
                ,
```

From what I have read under https://jwt.io/, I need the encoded key from the decoded details. As per the generating tokens, I think it uses HS256 algorithm. What are the steps to do this in javascript?

EDIT: After the user's answer, I did some changes to his code and I am currently generating half the JWT token. I am checking it with the already generated token on the server - Jaas.8x8

```
<script>
    const HMACSHA256 = (stringToSign, secret) => "not_implemented"

    // The header typically consists of two parts: 
    // the type of the token, which is JWT, and the signing algorithm being used, 
    // such as HMAC SHA256 or RSA.
    const header = {
        "kid": "vpaas-magic-cookie-07fabede3674457a84c95fsecretcode/myroom001",
        "alg": "RS256",
        "typ": "JWT"
    }
    const encodedHeaders = btoa(JSON.stringify(header))


    // create the signature part you have to take the encoded header, 
    // the encoded payload, a secret, the algorithm specified in the header, 
    // and sign that.
    const signature = HMACSHA256(`${encodedHeaders}`, "mysecret")


    console.log(`${encodedHeaders}.${signature}`)
</script>
```

The token that gets generated from code is

```
eyJraWQiOiJ2cGFhcy1tYWdpYy1jb29raWUtMDdmYWJlZGUzNjc0NDU3YTg0Yzk1ZmE4MGIxNGY1ZDcvVGVzdFJhdW0wMDEiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.not_implemented
```

And the token that is already generated online is:

```
eyJraWQiOiJ2cGFhcy1tYWdpYy1jb29raWUtMDdmYWJlZGUzNjc0NDU3YTg0Yzk1ZmE4MGIxNGY1ZDcvMTg1ZDY2LVNBTVBMRV9BUFAiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJqaXRzaSIsImV4cCI6MTYyMDM4ODU3NiwibmJmIjoxNjIwMzgxMzcxLCJpc3MiOiJjaGF0Iiwicm9vbSI6IioiLCJzdWIiOiJ2cGFhcy1tYWdpYy1jb29raWUtMDdmYWJlZGUzNjc0NDU3YTg0Yzk1ZmE4MGIxNGY1ZDciLCJjb250ZXh0Ijp7ImZlYXR1cmVzIjp7ImxpdmVzdHJlYW1pbmciOmZhbHNlLCJvdXRib3VuZC1jYWxsIjpmYWxzZSwidHJhbnNjcmlwdGlvbiI6ZmFsc2UsInJlY29yZGluZyI6ZmFsc2V9LCJ1c2VyIjp7Im1vZGVyYXRvciI6dHJ1ZSwibmFtZSI6IlRlc3QgVXNlciIsImlkIjoiYXV0aDB8NjA5M2EyYzM3Zjc3MGEwMDcxMGE5YzY5IiwiYXZhdGFyIjoiIiwiZW1haWwiOiJ0ZXN0LnVzZXJAY29tcGFueS5jb20ifX19.aNqg_VLXyafH8Se5rThe6TLz0F2AEnJSmuoZBQ4fXEm1PMx4SBRpelJsrmL76D_jKS5NT-GkuPDVcDgLv6nx9G4ywjws1AH4Lkt0FcJ3eH2OjbFI2WxPzJF_tDJbtPme5LJmGZwEa509v2QD0r-kr31M7FZ83S-kz3O1xKc33FnMJwNlqvgCSN2S0QwF6R5J01zDk41gCk0wGr3DXAmlz0FtCU0qJ5nN9iMUpr5QUY1D-hRApWMhoLPmxkuqnQKLjGwgxU8lh33wq_Laqu7qV57lYrI27er_c42YePwuitWEAAshQU4Ylf2v8sVRv06kQdFPVvICVdsTTI-DLbc3aQ
```

So basically the first few strings are right but the rest is not generated. I assume it has something to do with mysecret? What exactly is this?

[image: JWT Token]

Comment: "Jwt tokens get expired with a time limit of few hours so I am trying to find a way to generate the token in my code itself."  If you just need a longer lived token, you might consider adjusting the expiration timing on the token rather than reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: @HenryEcker thank you for your reply. I want to do that but the api-keys where I get my JWT token has a maximum limit of only 2 hours.

Comment: are you looking to do it with plain javascript or do you want a token by any means?

Comment: @TheFool I am trying to do it with plain js, I came across base64 header in javascript. Maybe that is the key to do this?

Comment: The header that you posted at the beginning of your question comes from a token signed with an asymmetric algorithm. To create such token you would need to have access to the Authorization Server's private certificate, which is used to sign tokens. The thing you're trying to do just doesn't seem right - you can't issue tokens in your code and expect them to work as tokens issued by some different Authorization Server. Unless you own the private keys of the server, only then you can mimic that behaviour.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All the instructions are written on this page, https://jwt.io/introduction.

For simplicity, I did not implement HMACSHA256 or use a library to do it. You need to implement this function.

- If you want to do it from the browser, which doesn't make much sense, [How to get HMAC with Crypto Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47329132/how-to-get-hmac-with-crypto-web-api).
- If you want to do it from node (backend), which makes more sense, you can look at this https://www.nodejsera.com/snippets/nodejs/sha256-hmac.html.

```js
const HMACSHA256 = (stringToSign, secret) => "not_implemented"

// The header typically consists of two parts: 
// the type of the token, which is JWT, and the signing algorithm being used, 
// such as HMAC SHA256 or RSA.
const header = {
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
const encodedHeaders = btoa(JSON.stringify(header))


// The second part of the token is the payload, which contains the claims.
// Claims are statements about an entity (typically, the user) and 
// additional data. There are three types of claims: 
// registered, public, and private claims.
const claims = {
    "role": "admin"
}
const encodedPlayload = btoa(JSON.stringify(claims))


// create the signature part you have to take the encoded header, 
// the encoded payload, a secret, the algorithm specified in the header, 
// and sign that.
const signature = HMACSHA256(`${encodedHeaders}.${encodedPlayload}`, "mysecret")
const encodedSignature = btoa(signature)

const jwt = `${encodedHeaders}.${encodedPlayload}.${encodedSignature}`
console.log({jwt})
```

Note, that my answer differs from your question in that it is using HS256 instead of RS256. If you want to learn more about the difference you can take a look here: [RS256 vs HS256: What's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239051/rs256-vs-hs256-whats-the-difference).

Comment: [jose](https://github.com/panva/jose) is JavaScript module for JSON Object Signing and Encryption, providing support for JSON Web Tokens (JWT)