# Need browser equivalent of this specific implementation of crypto.createHmac method

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, node-crypto

So, I have this piece of code that's written in Node.js

```
crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret).update(orderedParams).digest('hex')
```

I wish to bring this piece of code in the browser but that doesn't work since the 'crypto' library is not supported on the browser. Can somebody just help me re-create the same method in the browser?

Comment: Are there any examples using the standard browser crypto api without any libraries?

Answer (score 3):

An HMAC can be determined by most crypto libraries, e.g. [CryptoJS](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/) or [WebCrypto API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47332317/9014097).

The following example uses CryptoJS:

```js
var secret = 'my secret';
var orderedParams = 'the ordered params';

// Short
var hmac3 = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(orderedParams, secret).toString();
console.log(hmac3.replace(/(.{48})/g,'$1\n'));

// Progressive
var hmac2 = CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(CryptoJS.algo.SHA256, secret).update(orderedParams).finalize().toString();
console.log(hmac2.replace(/(.{48})/g,'$1\n'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Any way I can import "crypto-js" through NPM? I'm using webpack.

Comment: @Anonymous - _CryptoJS_ runs in the browser or as NodeJS. For installation details see e.g. [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js). Regarding _webpack_ I can't help you, I' m sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [crypto-browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-browserify).

It's a reimplementation of `crypto`, made it so that it can run on the Browser.

Comment: Can't get it to work for some reason. Getting `Can't resolve 'stream' in node_modules/cipher-base`.

Comment: @Anonymous Does this resolve your issue? https://github.com/crypto-browserify/cipher-base/issues/10