# AES GCM encrypt in nodejs and decrypt in browser?

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, aes-gcm, webcrypto-api

I am trying to encrypt a piece of string in nodejs and need to decrypt that in front end javascript. In nodejs I was using the crypto library and in front end using web crypto.
Facing some error while decrypting in the front end.

***NodeJS***

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(12);
const algorithm = 'aes-256-gcm';
let password = 'passwordpasswordpasswordpassword';
let text = 'Hello World!';
let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, password, iv);
let encrypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'hex');
encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
var tag = cipher.getAuthTag();
let cipherObj = {
    content: encrypted,
    tag: tag,
    iv: iv
}
```

***Front End***

```
let cipherObj;  //GET FROM BE
let aesKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
  "raw",
  Buffer.from('passwordpasswordpasswordpassword'), //password
  "AES-GCM",
  true,
  ["decrypt"]
);

let decrypted = await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(
  {
    name: "AES-GCM",
    iv: Buffer.from(cipherObj.iv),
    tagLength: 128
  },
  aesKey,
  Buffer.concat([Buffer.from(cipherObj.content), Buffer.from(cipherObj.tag)])
);
```

Decrypt function in the front-end is throwing an error.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): OperationError
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at zone.js:724
    at rejected (main.js:231)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:3820)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:138)
    at zone.js:872
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3811)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
```

***PS:*** I am using Angular 7 in front end

Comment: did you resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get this working with some changes:

1. I use SHA-256 to hash the password, so it can be any length. (The OP requires a 32-byte string.)
2. I added additional helper functions from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54099484/1026023) for converting buffers to/from hex.
3. I print the output cipherObj in JSON. This is your encrypted message payload.

***Helpers - NodeJS and Browser***

```js
// look up tables
var to_hex_array = [];
var to_byte_map = {};
for (var ord=0; ord<=0xff; ord++) {
    var s = ord.toString(16);
    if (s.length < 2) {
        s = "0" + s;
    }
    to_hex_array.push(s);
    to_byte_map[s] = ord;
}

// converter using lookups
function bufferToHex2(buffer) {
    var hex_array = [];
    //(new Uint8Array(buffer)).forEach((v) => { hex_array.push(to_hex_array[v]) });
    for (var i=0; i<buffer.length; i++) {
        hex_array.push(to_hex_array[buffer[i]]);
    }
    return hex_array.join('')
}
// reverse conversion using lookups
function hexToBuffer(s) {
    var length2 = s.length;
    if ((length2 % 2) != 0) {
        throw "hex string must have length a multiple of 2";
    }
    var length = length2 / 2;
    var result = new Uint8Array(length);
    for (var i=0; i<length; i++) {
        var i2 = i * 2;
        var b = s.substring(i2, i2 + 2);
        result[i] = to_byte_map[b];
    }
    return result;
}
```

The backend uses hex2buffer and the frontend uses buffer2hex, but you can just include that code in both.

So the backend code is the above helpers plus:

***NodeJS***

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(12);
const algorithm = 'aes-256-gcm';
let password = 'This is my password';
let key = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(password).digest();
let text = 'This is my test string, with  emoji in it!';
let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
let encrypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'hex');
encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
var tag = cipher.getAuthTag();
let cipherObj = {
    content: encrypted,
    tag: bufferToHex2(tag),
    iv: bufferToHex2(iv)
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(cipherObj));
```

The output changes every run due to random IV, but for example:

```
{"content":"22da4796365ac1466f40022dd4510266fa3e24900b816f365e308cf06c95237783d1043c7deeb45d00381f8ff9ed","tag":"b7007905163b2d4890c9452c8edc1821","iv":"eb4758787164f95ac22ee50d"}
```

So then the example frontend code is the above helper functions, plus:

***Browser***

```
let cipherObj;  //GET FROM BACKEND
// For example:
cipherObj = {"content":"22da4796365ac1466f40022dd4510266fa3e24900b816f365e308cf06c95237783d1043c7deeb45d00381f8ff9ed","tag":"b7007905163b2d4890c9452c8edc1821","iv":"eb4758787164f95ac22ee50d"}

let password = 'This is my password';

let enc = new TextEncoder();
let key = await window.crypto.subtle.digest({ name:"SHA-256" }, enc.encode(password));
let aesKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
  "raw",
  key,
  "AES-GCM",
  true,
  ["decrypt"]
);

let decrypted = await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(
  {
    name: "AES-GCM",
    iv: hexToBuffer(cipherObj.iv),
    tagLength: 128
  },
  aesKey,
  hexToBuffer(cipherObj.content + cipherObj.tag)
);

let dec = new TextDecoder();
console.log(dec.decode(decrypted));
// This is my test string, with  emoji in it!
```

Some crypto [reference examples](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples/).

Comment: Seriously, who thought that NodeJS and browsers should have different APIs every single time. 

Comment: Thank you SO much! Lol did you really post this 2 hours ago? I'm up at 2:30AM, struggling with this exact problem, and I was about to give up! What finally helped me is seeing that I need to append the auth tag to the message before decrypting! Also, the realization that the 16 BYTE tag node.js crypto produces matches the 128 BIT tag crypto.subtle expects! 2 minutes after finding your post, I had it working! Wish I could buy you a beer :)