# Using Ruby to verify Web Crypto SubtleCrypto key signature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, rsa, private-key, webcrypto-api

I am struggling to verify a message in Ruby that has been encrypted using a RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 private key.

The key pair is generated using the SubtleCrypto (Web Crypto) API. The public key is then sent to the server.

```
const usage = ["sign", "verify"];
const exponent = new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]);
const encryption = {name: 'RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5', modulusLength: 2048, publicExponent: exponent, hash: {name: "SHA-256"}};
const keys = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(encryption, true, usage);
const exportedKey = await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey("spki", keys.publicKey);
let body = window.btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(exportedKey)));
body = body.match(/.{1,64}/g).join('\n');
const publicKey `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n${body}\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`;

uploadToServer(publicKey);
```

I use the private key to encrypt the message

```
const message = "My Message";
const messageData = message.toArrayBuffer();
const signature = await window.crypto.subtle.sign({name: 'RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5'}, keys.privateKey, messageData);

sendSignatureToServer(signature.toString());
```

I can verify the signature successfully using JS, however, my Ruby logic always returns false.

```
publicKeyString = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n...\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"; # Sent to server in a previous request
signature = params[:signature]
message = "My Message"

publicKey = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(publicKeyString)
verified = publicKey.verify(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new, signature, message)
```

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem!

I used the code you posted (with a few changes regarding required output and some missing parts) to generate the RSA key pair and the signature:

```
const usage = ["sign", "verify"];
const exponent = new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]);
const encryption = {name: 'RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5', modulusLength: 2048, publicExponent: exponent, hash: {name: "SHA-256"}};
window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(encryption, true, usage).then(function (key){
    const message = "My Message";
    const messageData = new TextEncoder().encode(message);
    window.crypto.subtle.sign({name: 'RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5'}, key.privateKey, messageData).then(function (signature){
        console.log("Signature: " + buf2hex(signature));                    
        window.crypto.subtle.exportKey("spki", key.publicKey).then(function(publicKey){
            console.log("Public key: " + buf2hex(publicKey));
            let publicKeyBase64 = window.btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(publicKey)));
            publicKeyBase64 = publicKeyBase64.match(/.{1,64}/g).join('\n');
            publicKeyBase64 = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n${publicKeyBase64}\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`;
            console.log("Public key (base64): " + publicKeyBase64);
        });             
    });
});

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/40031979/9014097
function buf2hex(buffer) { // buffer is an ArrayBuffer
    return Array.prototype.map.call(new Uint8Array(buffer), x => ('00' + x.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
}
```

Since the verification on the JavaScript-side works for you, the issue should not be in this part, so that the changes should be unproblematic. A typical output of the JavaScript-code for the public key (Base64) is:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA2txHYgsCGfS9eZfys/m1
P1rhi7x1frM02QbgdR1oXjP6qyarvPHJSbOnpZR7FkuZ4Y1q+DLb98iNDw+AlP0z
HxE6Q2qsRHIfjeperJTtKXLNfrBtdVrp+UbtpiyU6HOXyXt/8joIE1s4+AMNIK47
XghXB1RXKzt/WO4ykldSYAcx00Hfjf5i1ABc16jF0dSfSDDEmWj6WCYn64K9yBOO
I1s8ijmwDyadK5Mgs1YPaPGHtuRMatHn02jXUyhyYWMRdd6evlan1MhHYv1z517M
Wq+Blx/+5vJw58SYn4/i9Pn5VbscQhhwJVxLW8BWQUEl9zeTXmMSWMxGT8+yP69f
hwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

and for the corresponding signature (hexadecimal):

```
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
```

Now to the interesting part: The code on the Ruby-side is with these data:

```
require 'openssl'

def hex2bin(s)
    s.scan(/../).map { |x| x.hex }.pack('c*')
end

publicKeyString = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA2txHYgsCGfS9eZfys/m1
P1rhi7x1frM02QbgdR1oXjP6qyarvPHJSbOnpZR7FkuZ4Y1q+DLb98iNDw+AlP0z
HxE6Q2qsRHIfjeperJTtKXLNfrBtdVrp+UbtpiyU6HOXyXt/8joIE1s4+AMNIK47
XghXB1RXKzt/WO4ykldSYAcx00Hfjf5i1ABc16jF0dSfSDDEmWj6WCYn64K9yBOO
I1s8ijmwDyadK5Mgs1YPaPGHtuRMatHn02jXUyhyYWMRdd6evlan1MhHYv1z517M
Wq+Blx/+5vJw58SYn4/i9Pn5VbscQhhwJVxLW8BWQUEl9zeTXmMSWMxGT8+yP69f
hwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----' 

signature = hex2bin('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')

message = "My Message"

publicKey = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(publicKeyString)
puts publicKey.verify(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new, signature, message) # provides true
```

The verification is successful, as can be easily checked on https://repl.it/languages/ruby!

Since the verification on the Ruby-side principally works, I can only guess that your data (key and/or signature) might be changed during sending 
or reconstruction on the Ruby-side, so that the verification fails. A byte-wise comparison of the public keys and the signatures on both sides 
could clarify this.