# How can I get window.crypto.subtle to output the same signature as the 'crypto' js library?

Tags: javascript, encryption, browser, cryptography, signature

I'm wanting to use the built in browser crypto object instead of importing the crypto library in my browser project.

I want to not need this.

> npm i crypto

The following code illustrates trying to sign a simple message using both libraries, however I get a different result when using the built in crypto object.  The outputs are logged to console.

```
// START CRYPTO LIBRARY METHOD
import crypto from 'crypto';

const HMAC_SHA256_KEY = {
    API_KEY: '***',
    SECRET_KEY: '***'
};

const queryString = `timestamp=${(new Date().getTime())}`;

const signature = crypto
    .createHmac('sha256', HMAC_SHA256_KEY.SECRET_KEY)
    .update(queryString)
    .digest('hex')

console.log("standard encrypt", signature);

// START NATIVE LIBRARY METHOD    
const getUtf8Bytes = (str: string) => {
    return new Uint8Array(
        [...(unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)))].map(c => c.charCodeAt(0))
    );
};

// @ts-ignore
const builtInCrypto = window.crypto || window.msCrypto;
builtInCrypto.subtle.importKey(
    'raw',
    getUtf8Bytes(HMAC_SHA256_KEY.SECRET_KEY),
    {
        name: 'HMAC', hash: 'SHA-256'
    },
    true, ['sign']
).then(key => {
    builtInCrypto.subtle.sign(
        'HMAC',
        key,
        getUtf8Bytes(queryString))
        .then(signature => {
            console.log('builtIn Signature', btoa(String.fromCharCode(...(new Uint8Array(signature)))));
        })
})
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong, but what? Why am I getting a different output for the native encryption?

Answer (score 2):

For the *same* values of `HMAC_SHA256_KEY.SECRET_KEY` and `queryString` (the last parameter depends on time and therefore has a different value for each run) both scripts return the *same* HMac but in *different* encodings, resulting in different output. In the *NodeJS / crypto* code the HMac is hex encoded, in the *JavaScript / Web Crypto API* code Base64 encoded.

To make sure that the output is identical, the same encoding must be used in both scripts. Either the HMac in the *JavaScript / Web Crypto API* code must also be hex encoded, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40031979) for a suitable method, or the HMac in the *NodeJS / crypto* code must be Base64 encoded (by passing `'base64'` instead of `'hex'` as argument of `digest`).