# Convert binary form to Base 64 for Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, binary, base64

in PHP I have this code to convert a string to binary and encode to Base 64:

```
    <?php
$value = pack('H*', "b4h3h347h38f3g734ff");
echo base64_encode($value);
```

But how I can do that in Javascript ?

Thank you!

Comment: I  found the solution thank you

Answer (score 0):

See [text_to_binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430633/how-to-convert-text-to-binary-code-in-javascript) here in SO.

Use btoa() and atob() to convert to and from base64 encoding.

Comment: I tried that method but when I compare the result of PHP and Javascript, it is totally different

Comment: You have a similar way in javascript with the turbocommons library, easy and extensively tested: https://turboframework.org/en/app/stringutils/base64-encode