# How to convert string to binary on 7 bits? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, binary

I need to convert a string to binary specifically on 7 bits.

```
'%'.charCodeAt().toString(2)
```

The above code return 100101, I think it convert on 8 bits. (so this link [How to convert text to binary code in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430633/how-to-convert-text-to-binary-code-in-javascript) is not helping me).

`%` is equal to 0100101 in binary on 7 bits.

The only links I found on SO are about Java.

Comment: What if you calculate the length of the binary and if it less than 7 bin then add zero(s) at the left of the binary number?

Comment: @SajeebAhamed nice idea, i'm gonna try!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the method `String.prototype.padStart()`

```js
const sevenBitBinary = (char) => char.charCodeAt().toString(2).padStart(7, '0');

console.log(sevenBitBinary('%'));
```

Comment: if `char`  have `ascii`  bigger than 128 ,it will show 8 bits

Answer (score 1):

You can add 0s add the beginning with [`.padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart).

Answer (score 0):

I think it can help you

```js
function get7BitsBinaryString(number) {
  var result = '';
  var bits = [64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1];
  bits.forEach(bit => {
    if ((bit & number) === bit) {
      result += '1';
    } else {
      result += '0';
    }
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(get7BitsBinaryString('%'.charCodeAt()));
```